# How to check whether an object is a date?

Tags: javascript, date

I have an annoying bug in on a webpage:

> date.GetMonth() is not a function

So, I suppose that I am doing something wrong. The variable `date` is not an object of type `Date`. **How can I check for a datatype in Javascript?** I tried to add a `if (date)`, but it doesn't work.

```
function getFormatedDate(date) {
    if (date) {
       var month = date.GetMonth();
    }
}
```

So, if I want to write defensive code and prevent the date (which is not one) to be formatted, how do I do that?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I don't want to check the format of the date, but I want to be sure that the parameter passed to the method `getFormatedDate()` is of type `Date`.

Comment: In case it should be also validated whether the _date_ is not an `Invalid Date`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44198641/5846045

Answer (score 1529, accepted):

As an alternative to duck typing via

```
typeof date.getMonth === 'function'
```

you can use the `instanceof` operator, i.e. But it will return true for invalid dates too, e.g. `new Date('random_string')` is also instance of Date

```
date instanceof Date
```

This will fail if objects are passed across frame boundaries.

A work-around for this is to check the object's class via

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]'
```

Comment: Out of interest do you know the reason for this failing when passing across frame boundaries?

Comment: @Simon: JS globals are local to the current global object (aka `window` or `self`); different frames have their own global objects, and their properties (ie globals) refer to distinct objects: `Date` in frame1 is a different function object than `Date` in frame2; the same is true for `Date.prototype`, which is the reason for the `instanceof` failure: `Date.prototype` from frame1 is not part of the prototype chain of `Date` instances from frame2

Comment: For elaboration on the `instanceof` method failing across frame boundaries, see [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.instanceof) :

"... `instanceof` does not work on objects that originate from different JavaScript contexts (e.g. different documents in a web browser), since their constructors will not be the exact same object."

Comment: Christoph, what do you call "frame"? IFRAME, each frame in FRAMESET or something else (I mean JS-specific, not the HTML-thing)?

Comment: @Paul each HTML `frame`/`iframe` has its own JS context, and thus an own `Date` object. You can find all the frames in the [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frames) collection, and the corresponding Date objects via `window.frames[i].window.Date`. For example, try `window.frames[0].window.Date == Date`

Comment: @krillgar, I'd argue new Date(/anything/) is an instanceof Date. It's just an invalid instance.

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn I agree that it is an instance of a Date object, but if it's an invalid instance, then how does that help you if you're trying to do anything constructive with it?

Comment: Detecting a Date type object (as opposed to a plain Object or a string) and validating an object you expect to be a Date are two different tasks.

There are a number of situations where the input to your function could be one of a number of different data types. In my case, I can trust that any Date object I get is valid (it's not coming straight from a client)

If validating is a concern, here is a post with a number of options.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: FYI Doing something like `date.setUTCHours(0) instanceof Date` will return false but executing it then doing `date instanceof Date` returns true

Comment: @Kian that is because `date.setUTCHours(0)` does not return the date object. It returns the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC. That value is a number so `date.setUTCHours(0) instanceof Date` will be false.

Comment: @Roshdy If you assing any integer to `dateVariable`, then `(new Date(dateVariable) != "Invalid Date")` will evaluate to true. Some strings also can be assigned to this variable in a way that the whole statement evaluates to true. So it doesn't work for what OP wants.

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date('invalid_date')) === '[object Date]'` still returns `true`

Comment: 'typeof date.getMonth === function' would return true if the object has a getMonth function but it is not really a date. So, there is a small risk there.

Comment: even invalid dates have a getMonth function. You can make a small change with: `isNaN(new Date('20171212').getMonth())` if you assume a "real" date always have a month, because then it has to be a number, or it's a NaN

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]'` worked well for me, thanks!

Answer (score 207):

You can use the following code:

```
(myvar instanceof Date) // returns true or false
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted or more upvoted answer? Simply checking if date has a .getMonth property could trigger a false positive.

Comment: instanceof can trigger false negatives, see Christoph's comment to his own answer.

Comment: @doremi Here is a demo of `instanceof` triggering false negative: https://jsbin.com/vufufoq/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Since both methods are equally flawed. You have to use @Jan's method in the debate above to make sure `getMonth()` doesn't return NaN on its false positive instance, at least using `instanceof Date` at least *looks* the part.

Comment: if I do `new Date("asdf") instanceof Date` it's returning true.

Comment: `date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date)`
It also checks that it is an instance of a date, and that it is a valid date (each of the tests alone is not completely reliable)

Answer (score 121):

In order to check if the value is a valid type of the standard JS-date object, you can make use of this predicate:

```
function isValidDate(date) {
  return date && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === "[object Date]" && !isNaN(date);
}
```

1. `date` checks whether the parameter was not a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (`undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, etc..)
2. `Object.prototype.toString.call(date)` returns a [native string representation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) of the given object type - In our case `"[object Date]"`. Because [`date.toString()` overrides its parent method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString#Examples), we need to [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) the method from `Object.prototype` directly which ..

   - Bypasses user-defined object type with the same constructor name (e.g.: "Date")
   - Works across different JS contexts (e.g. iframes) in [contrast to `instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_context_(e.g._frames_or_windows)) or [`Date.prototype.isPrototypeOf`](https://jsbin.com/vufufoq/edit?js,console).
3. `!isNaN(date)` finally checks whether the value was not an `Invalid Date`.

Comment: Wow `isNaN` can be used to check a `Date`. That's some PHP level of inanity.

Comment: @Nick a date is a number though.

Comment: @Josiah Well, sure, removing all context there's a timestamp there: `typeof Date.now() === "number"`, but: `typeof new Date() === "object"`. More realistically, though, a date is a time and a location in space.

Comment: This worked for me in a highly volatile environment where every possibility of string values could exist (actual dates, random letters, blanks, random characters, etc).

Answer (score 40):

The function is `getMonth()`, not `GetMonth()`.

Anyway, you can check if the object has a getMonth property by doing this. It doesn't necessarily mean the object is a Date, just any object which has a getMonth property.

```
if (date.getMonth) {
    var month = date.getMonth();
}
```

Comment: Check whether it's callable: `if (date.getMonth && typeof date.getMonth === "function") {...}`

Answer (score 32):

This is a pretty simple approach if you're not concerned about iframes / other contexts.

```js
// isNaN(Invalid Date) == true
if (date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date)) { // isNaN wont accept a date in typescript, use date.getTime() instead to produce a number
    console.log("is date!");
}
```

- Checks if object is actually a `Date` and not something that looks like one. Any object could have a `getMonth` function.
- Ensures the Date is not an `Invalid Date`
- Doesn't pass a value into `new Date()` where a number or even a string could be turned into a Date.

If you need to support iframes and different contexts you can use the accepted answer but add an extra check to identify invalid dates.

```js
// isNaN(Invalid Date) == true
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]' && !isNaN(date)) {
    console.log("is date!");
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this warning: "Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'"... Do I really need this second check? Indeed, isNaN is for numbers...

Comment: Sounds like a typescript issue? You can use `getTime()` to account for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426680/typescript-isnan-not-accepting-date-object

Answer (score 25):

As indicated above, it's probably easiest to just check if the function exists before using it.  If you really care that it's a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), and not just an object with a `getMonth()` function, try this:

```
function isValidDate(value) {
    var dateWrapper = new Date(value);
    return !isNaN(dateWrapper.getDate());
}
```

This will create either a clone of the value if it's a `Date`, or create an invalid date.  You can then check if the new date's value is invalid or not.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. However, if you pass a single digit such as 0, or 1, it treats that as a valid Date... any thoughts?

Comment: That's right, @RicardoSanchez.  You probably want to use the accepted answer (`Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Date]'`) if it's possible you'll be getting numbers.  The method in this answer really tells you whether the `value` is convertible to a `Date`.

Answer (score 18):

For all types I cooked up an Object prototype function. It may be of use to you

```
Object.prototype.typof = function(chkType){
      var inp        = String(this.constructor),
          customObj  = (inp.split(/\({1}/))[0].replace(/^\n/,'').substr(9),
          regularObj = Object.prototype.toString.apply(this),
          thisType   = regularObj.toLowerCase()
                        .match(new RegExp(customObj.toLowerCase()))
                       ? regularObj : '[object '+customObj+']';
     return chkType
            ? thisType.toLowerCase().match(chkType.toLowerCase()) 
               ? true : false
            : thisType;
}
```

Now you can check *any* type like this:

```
var myDate     = new Date().toString(),
    myRealDate = new Date();
if (myRealDate.typof('Date')) { /* do things */ }
alert( myDate.typof() ); //=> String
```

[**Edit march 2013**] based on progressing insight this is a better method:

```
Object.prototype.is = function() {
        var test = arguments.length ? [].slice.call(arguments) : null
           ,self = this.constructor;
        return test ? !!(test.filter(function(a){return a === self}).length)
               : (this.constructor.name ||
                  (String(self).match ( /^function\s*([^\s(]+)/im)
                    || [0,'ANONYMOUS_CONSTRUCTOR']) [1] );
}
// usage
var Some = function(){ /* ... */}
   ,Other = function(){ /* ... */}
   ,some = new Some;
2..is(String,Function,RegExp);        //=> false
2..is(String,Function,Number,RegExp); //=> true
'hello'.is(String);                   //=> true
'hello'.is();                         //-> String
/[a-z]/i.is();                        //-> RegExp
some.is();                            //=> 'ANONYMOUS_CONSTRUCTOR'
some.is(Other);                       //=> false
some.is(Some);                        //=> true
// note: you can't use this for NaN (NaN === Number)
(+'ab2').is(Number);                 //=> true
```

Answer (score 13):

*UnderscoreJS* and *Lodash* have a function called [`.isDate()`](https://lodash.com/docs#isDate) which appears to be exactly what you need. It's worth looking at their respective implementations: [Lodash isDate](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/isDate.js), [UnderscoreJs](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1bfc9f1fb811060c745e7025ec55e35f87c1d43b/underscore.js#L1321)

Answer (score 13):

The best way I found is:

```
!isNaN(Date.parse("some date test"))
//
!isNaN(Date.parse("22/05/2001"))  // true
!isNaN(Date.parse("blabla"))  // false
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Your true line actually is false and the question is about checking if an object is a date object...

Comment: @jspassov answer is more accurate with if a string is a date or not. That I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: This is the best answer for simply checking whether a string is a date or not

Comment: this is not working for string with numbers (Ex -: test 1)

Comment: Yep, this way your system is taking 1 as YEAR and the date of 01 of January 0001 is indeed date :-)

Answer (score 8):

Instead of all the workarounds you can use the following:

```
dateVariable = new Date(date);
if (dateVariable == 'Invalid Date') console.log('Invalid Date!');
```

I found this hack better!

Comment: This does not work unless you put `toString()` after `dateVariable` as an invalid date does not return a string

Answer (score 6):

arrow function

```
const isValidDate = (value: any) => value instanceof Date && !isNaN(value);
```

Function:

```
function isValidDate(d) {
  return d instanceof Date && !isNaN(d);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been using a much simpler way but am not sure if this is only available in ES6 or not.

```
let a = {name: "a", age: 1, date: new Date("1/2/2017"), arr: [], obj: {} };
console.log(a.name.constructor.name); // "String"
console.log(a.age.constructor.name);  // "Number"
console.log(a.date.constructor.name); // "Date"
console.log(a.arr.constructor.name);  // "Array"
console.log(a.obj.constructor.name);  // "Object"
```

However, this will not work on null or undefined since they have no constructor.

Comment: Any custom made object with the constructor name "Date" returns `"Date"` too which is as risky as just checking if the parameter has `getMonth` property.

Comment: @boghyon sounds like whomever creates an object with the constructor name of a already predefined Javascript standard library is not following best practices in the first place. That would be like downloading lodash then creating your own lodash module and expecting things to work.

Comment: note that if the value is `null` then `value.constructor.name` throws an exception.

Answer (score 4):

```
const myDate = Date.now(); // 1679252208851
const myDate2 = new Date(); // Sun Mar 19 2023 20:56:59 GMT+0200 (Восточная Европа, стандартное время)

console.log(myDate instanceof Date); // false
console.log(myDate2 instanceof Date); // true
```

BUT

```
const myDate3 = new Date(myDate); // Sun Mar 19 2023 20:56:59 GMT+0200 (Восточная Европа, стандартное время)
console.log(myDate3 instanceof Date); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you're using `Node.js` you can check if an object is a `Date` by using the `isDate` method of the `util` module like this.

```
const util = require('util');

const now = new Date();
console.log(util.types.isDate(now))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check if a function specific to the Date object exists:

```
function getFormatedDate(date) {
    if (date.getMonth) {
        var month = date.getMonth();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use short form

```
function getClass(obj) {
  return {}.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
}
alert( getClass(new Date) ); //Date
```

or something like this:

```
(toString.call(date)) == 'Date'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use moment

```
import moment from 'moment';

moment(myvar).isValid(); //  return true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will return `true` if it's Date or `false` otherwise:

```
function isDate(myDate) {
    return myDate.constructor.toString().indexOf("Date") > -1;
}
```

Comment: `isDate(new (function AnythingButNotDate(){ })())` returns `true`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant:

```
Date.prototype.isPrototypeOf(myDateObject)
```

Comment: Nice and short! But unfortunately, it has the [same issue as `instanceof`](https://jsbin.com/vufufoq/edit?js,console).

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann in case of iFrame it may look like:

`iWindow.Date.prototype.isPrototypeOf(iWindow.date); // true`

`iWindow.date instanceof iWindow.Date; // true`

Answer (score 1):

An approach using a try/catch

```js
function getFormattedDate(date = new Date()) {
  try {
    date.toISOString();
  } catch (e) {
    date = new Date();
  }
  return date;
}

console.log(getFormattedDate());
console.log(getFormattedDate('AAAA'));
console.log(getFormattedDate(new Date('AAAA')));
console.log(getFormattedDate(new Date(2018, 2, 10)));
```

Answer (score 1):

with the following approach, you can even check date no to be "Invalid Date"

```
if(!!date.getDate()){
    console.log('date is valid')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually date will be of type `Object`. But you can check if the object has `getMonth` method and if it is callable.

```
function getFormatedDate(date) {
    if (date && date.getMonth && date.getMonth.call) {
       var month = date.getMonth();
    }
}
```

Comment: Christoph's answer is more accurate. Having a 'call' property doesn't necessarily mean it is a function!

Answer (score 0):

We can also validate it by below code

```
var a = new Date();
a.constructor === Date
/*
true
*/
```

[image]

Comment: The constructor of `function Date() {/*...*/}` is also `Date`. I.e. simply comparing the constructor function is too error-prone which often results in false positives. Bypass user-defined object type with https://stackoverflow.com/a/44198641/5846045

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508022/7025986), this solution works in my case(I needed to check whether the value recieved from API is a date or not):

```
!isNaN(Date.parse(new Date(YourVariable)))
```

This way, if it is some random string coming from a client, or any other object, you can find out if it is a Date-like object.

Comment: This worked perfect for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with React hooks where the Date would come in later / lazy loaded and then the initial state can't be null, it won't pass ts checks, but apparently an empty Object does the trick then! :)

```
const [birthDate, setBirthDate] = React.useState({})

<input
  value={birthDate instanceof Date ? birthDate.toISOString() : ''}
  name="birthDay"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach of detecting an valid date.

```js
const isDate = ( str ) => {
    let timestamp = Date.parse( str );
    if (!isNaN(timestamp)) return new Date(timestamp);
    return false
}

console.log( isDate("2020-11-11T12:12:55.123Z") )

console.log( isDate("17/July/2024") )
console.log( "getMonth: ",  isDate("17/July/2024").getMonth() )

console.log( isDate("Invalid something") )
```

Comment: It looks more like a TryParse than a boolean: will `new Date` in your code ever return "non true" result?

Answer (score 0):

I've started leaning on this function.

```js
/**
 * @Returns Object type 
 *    - betterTypeOf(); `undefined`
 *    - betterTypeOf(null); `null`
 *    - betterTypeOf(NaN); `number`
 *    - betterTypeOf(5); `number`
 *    - betterTypeOf({}); `object`
 *    - betterTypeOf([]); `array`
 *    - betterTypeOf(''); `string`
 *    - betterTypeOf(function () {}); `function`
 *    - betterTypeOf(/a/) `regexp`
 *    - betterTypeOf(new Date()) `date`
 */
export function betterTypeOf(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1).toLowerCase();
}
```

And then...

```js
if (betterTypeOf(myDateVar) === 'date' {
  console.log('it is a date')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Typescript you could check using the Date type:

```
const formatDate( date: Date ) => {}
```

Answer (score -4):

Couldn't you just use

```
function getFormatedDate(date) {
    if (date.isValid()) {
       var month = date.GetMonth();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, only the date object has the `isValid` method

Comment: @grumpy @nikkwong No and no. The standard date object doesn't have `isValid`. Only [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) has such an API.

Comment: `isValid` method is not available in date object, hence this throws up an error.