# Safari JS cannot parse YYYY-MM-DD date format?

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime, safari

In a project I am working on, I need to validate a date entered into an `<input type="date">`

With Safari 4/5 (on Mac OSX) the Javascript fails to parse dates of the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, returning `NaN` instead of the expected epoch timestamp.

I am using the following technique to validate the field just before the form is submitted:

```
//value = '2010-06-21'
var stamp = Date.parse(value);
if (isNaN(stamp)) {
    //notify user
} else {
    value = new Date(stamp).format_mysql();
}
```

Where `format_mysql()` is a prototype function that formats the date (correctly) into MySQL Date-Time format (YYYY-MM-DD).

Replacing the `-`'s with `/`'s (YYYY/MM/DD) yields a "correct" timestamp.

I should note that the field should accept any date format, not just YYYY-MM-DD, and that though I would like to, I cannot use libraries like Date.js

**How can I fix this, or is there a better way to parse/validate a date?**

Comment: I have Safari 5.17, and this work fine for me (tested on iOS 5.12 aswell):         when = Date.parse("2013-01-29 08:30");

Comment: The strings accepted by the `Date()` constructor vary across browsers, but the safest one does seem to be YYYY/MM/DD--see http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html .

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The behavior of the [`Date.parse`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.4.2) method is implementation dependent, on ECMAScript 5, this method can parse ISO8601 formatted dates, but I would recommend you to make the parsing manually.

Some time ago I've made a simple function, that can handle a format specifier argument:

```
function parseDate(input, format) {
  format = format || 'yyyy-mm-dd'; // default format
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g), 
      i = 0, fmt = {};
  // extract date-part indexes from the format
  format.replace(/(yyyy|dd|mm)/g, function(part) { fmt[part] = i++; });

  return new Date(parts[fmt['yyyy']], parts[fmt['mm']]-1, parts[fmt['dd']]);
}

parseDate('06.21.2010', 'mm.dd.yyyy');
parseDate('21.06.2010', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
parseDate('2010/06/21', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
parseDate('2010-06-21');
```

Also you could detect the ECMAScript 5 behavior to parse ISO formatted dates, you can check if the `Date.prototype.toISOString` is available, e.g.:

```
if (typeof Date.prototype.toISOString == "function") {
  // ES5 ISO date parsing available
}
```

Comment: +1, you beat me to it.  As advice to the OP, I would consider moving away from a single input element for dates to avoid the situation where a user inputs dates in their own locale (e.g. mixing up dd and mm).  Either that or use a read-only input and a date picker control.

Comment: Unless I understand wrongly, your function would only apply when I know the date format before hand, correct?

@Andy E's head: Separate inputs is a good idea, and something I will look into. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Austin, yes, you have to know the format somehow, otherwise you will have a lot of ambiguities, e.g. `"01/02/2010"` vs `"02/01/2010"`, which one January 2, and which is February 1?

Comment: @CMS how to just display dd/mm/yyyy using ur function

Comment: @CMS output using ur function Sun May 03 1908 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  but just need 03/09/1908

Comment: I found that `typeof Date.prototype.toISOString == "function"` returned true on Safari 5.1.2 so I had to change this check for `Date.parse`

Comment: As brendo mentioned, older versions of Safari on iOS have the `toISOString` function but cannot parse correctly. Use something like this to detect... 

`var canParseIso = !isNaN( Date.parse('2012-01-01T01:01:00.000Z') )`

Answer (score 23):

Generally DD-MM-YYYY format is not support in safari.

value =  2010/06/21 ; //should work.

(or)

value  = new Date('2010-06-21'.replace(/-/g, "/"));

Comment: Really helpful  ; )

Comment: second one worked can you explain little bit

Answer (score 3):

> the field should accept any date format

You don't mean what you think you mean.

- It's difficult to reliably distinguish between M/D/Y (US) and D/M/Y (UK). D.M.Y is more common in the UK, but by no means universal.
- Good luck with dates before around 1600 — the Gregorian (solar) calendar was introduced in 1582, and was only (mostly universally) adopted in the 20th century (Wikipedia gives 1929). February 30 was a valid date Sweden.
- OS X gives you a choice of 13 (!) calendars, though the default is Gregorian.

Instead, I recommend using a calendar widget. I think JQuery has one, but ICBW.

Comment: Well, I'm targeting a fairly small US audience, looking at dates from 2000+, and more than likely the Gregorian calendar. Yes, jQuery has a datepicker widget as part of its UI package, but I cannot use it :(. When I say "any date format" I mean "June 21, 2010", "6/21/10", "2010-06-21", etc all represent the same date.

Comment: If you mean "any vaguely common date format in the US", you probably have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an unambiguous date from input, 
but you still need to check it, so a user doesn't give you April 31.

```
<fieldset id= "localdate"> 
<select id= "monthselect" size= "1"> 
<option selected= "selected"> January</option> 
<option> February</option> 
<option> March</option> 
<option> April</option> 
<option> May</option> 
<option> June</option> 
<option> July</option> 
<option> August</option> 
<option> September</option> 
<option> October</option> 
<option> November</option> 
<option> December</option> 
</select> 
<label> Date: <input name= "inputdate" size= "2" value= "1"> </label> 
<label> Year: <input name= "inputyear" size= "4" value= "2010"> </label> 
</fieldset>
```

shortcut for document.getElementsByName

function byName(s, n){
    n= n || 0;
    return document.getElementsByName(s)[n];
}

```
function getDateInput(){
    var day, y= parseInt(byName('inputyear').value),
    m= byName('monthselect').selectedIndex,
    d= parseInt(byName('inputdate').value);

    if(!y || y<1000 || y> 3000) throw 'Bad Year '+y;
    if((!d || d<1 || d> 32) throw 'Bad Date '+d;
    day= new Date(y,m,d);
    if(day.getDate()!= d) throw 'Bad Date '+d;
    value= day.format_mysql();
}
```

you can preset the fields to reflect the current date onload

```
onload= function(){
    var now= new Date();
    byName('inputyear').value= now.getFullYear();
    byName('monthselect').selectedIndex= now.getMonth();
    byName('inputdate').value= now.getDate();
}
```