# Countdown timer not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a countdown timer that is working prefect in chrome, however when I view in safari it shows NAN for all the numbers and also if I set the date in the past it will not trigger my model in the else statement. I have looked all over the net for a solution but have found none.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#popupTimer').delay(1000).fadeIn(600);

        // Set the date we're counting down to  (*** Set to Apr 9th after testing ***)
        var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 3, 2017 24:00:00").getTime();

        // Update the count down every 1 second
        var x = setInterval(function() {

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Display the result in the element with id="display"
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = days + " Days " + hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ";

            // If the count down is finished,
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                $(".myDIV").hide();
                $('#chooseProductThree').show();
                $(".panel-heading").addClass("active-panel");
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: do you do the tests from a windows device?

Comment: @Konstantinos Testes were done on a Mac

Comment: maybe Safari does not understand new Date getTime, so change it with Date.parse @Cory Kelly

Comment: different browsers have different date formats they can "parse" ... date strings are a nightmare for cross browser compatibility - look into libraries (momentjs is popular) which do much of the heavy lifting for you

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the advice, I found a solution with momentjs

Answer (score 3):

**first write below function**

```
function parseDateString (dateString) {
            var matchers = [];
            matchers.push(/^[0-9]*$/.source);
            matchers.push(/([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{4}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source);
            matchers.push(/[0-9]{4}([\/\-][0-9]{1,2}){2}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source);
            matchers = new RegExp(matchers.join("|"));
            if (dateString instanceof Date) {
                return dateString;
            }
            if (String(dateString).match(matchers)) {
                if (String(dateString).match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
                    dateString = Number(dateString);
                }
                if (String(dateString).match(/\-/)) {
                    dateString = String(dateString).replace(/\-/g, "/");
                }
                return new Date(dateString);
            } else {
                throw new Error("Couldn't cast `" + dateString + "` to a date object.");
            }
        }
```

> **↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ then call this function like below ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓**

```
var EndTime = "2019-05-10 00:00:00";
countDownDate=Date.parse(_self.parseDateString(EndTime));
```

Comment: `var arr = "2010-03-15 10:30:00".split(/[- :]/),
    date = new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);` this is easier to implement (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5324266/2173276)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here is what I solved it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const second = 1000;
    const minute = second * 60;
    const hour = minute * 60;
    const day = hour * 24;

    // Have to split time funny for IOS and Safari NAN and timezone bug
    var timeParsed = '{{ $startTime }}'.replace(' ', 'T').split(/[^0-9]/);
    var countDown = new Date(new Date (timeParsed[0],timeParsed[1]-1,timeParsed[2],timeParsed[3],timeParsed[4],timeParsed[5])).getTime();

    let x = setInterval(function() {
        let now = new Date().getTime();
        let distance = countDown - now;
        if(Math.floor(distance / (day)) > 0) {
            document.getElementById("days_line").style.display = "inline-block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("days_line").style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day));
        document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour));
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute));
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            $('.counter-container').fadeOut(function() {
                $('.counter-message').fadeIn();
            });
        } else {
            $('.counter-container').fadeIn();
        }
    }, second)
</script>
```

note `{{ startTime }}` is not javascript but a PHP import from blade. Just put in your date there.

Answer (score 1):

Have just had this issue and fixed with the following date format (note: the '`/`' and not a '`-`' separating the day, month & year...

`"2019/05/10T00:00:00Z";`

Answer (score 0):

I assume safari cannot parse the date in this line:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 3, 2017 24:00:00").getTime();
```

Change to this:

```
var countDownDate = Date.parse("Apr 3, 2017 24:00:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in the date format
It turns out that Safari doesn't support that date/time format
Switching to one of the supported formats below will fix the issue

- yyyy, mm, dd
- yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, ss
- mm/dd/yyyy
- mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
- milliseconds
- Day Mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss

For more details, you check this out https://chrispennington.blog/blog/safari-does-not-show-new-date-from-javascript/