# UTC date in Date() object outputs differently in Safari

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, safari, utc

```
var dateString = "2018-01-01T00:00:00";
new Date(dateString);
```

Chrome, Edge and Firefox (right):

```
Mon Jan 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Safari (wrong):

```
Sun Dec 31 2017 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

What can I do to make Safari oblige to January 1st? I do not want to use `moment.js` or another framework to resolve this. If you are a JavaScript `Date()` object master, please point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Safari's parser is buggy (and maybe others), so parse it yourself (3 lines of code).

Comment: Did my answer fully answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers handle date strings differently. Mozilla notes this problem on their `Date` documentation page:

> Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. - [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

They also note this on their `Date.parse()` documentation page, which gives a hint as to the solution:

> It is not recommended to use Date.parse as until ES5, parsing of strings was entirely implementation dependent. There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many different formats are to be accommodated). - [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324178/javascript-date-parsing-on-iphone), you can best split up the string and use the separated `Date()` constructor. Example code:

```
var arr = "2018-01-01T00:00:00".split(/\D/);
var date = new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
```

In one function:

```
function parseDateString(dateString) {
    var arr = dateString.split(/\D/);
    return new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Updated answer to include more documentation.

Comment: It's a bit simpler to use `"...".split(/\D/)`. ;-)