# Formatting UTC date don't works in Safari with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to format a DB UTC timestamp to the local timezone. For that I'm trying this:

```
new Date( "2020-03-13 18:40:45 UTC".replace( /\s/, 'T' ) )
```

First I had this:

```
new Date( "2020-03-13 18:40:45 UTC" )
```

Which works in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. So I did some research and came up with the replace. Because of my replace I'm getting now `Invalid Date` in every browser. I've now idea why... What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTC date in Date() object outputs differently in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515136/utc-date-in-date-object-outputs-differently-in-safari)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava - That's more an answer to the OP's implicit question from before they did the `replace`. :-) This one is more about the "UTC" at the end, since having done the replace it doesn't work at all for them now.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your string is in [the officially supported format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), since anything else is falling back to *"...any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats."*

The space needs to be a `T`, and `UTC` needs to be `Z` with no space in front of it. (No need for a regular expression here.)

```
new Date("2020-03-13 18:40:45 UTC".replace(" ", "T").replace(" UTC", "Z"))
```

Live Example:

```js
const dt = new Date("2020-03-13 18:40:45 UTC".replace(" ", "T").replace(" UTC", "Z"));
console.log(dt.toISOString());
```

It would appear that Chrome and Firefox have implementation-specific heuristics/formats that would make them accept it with the space and UTC, but not with the T and UTC. :-)

Comment: Perfect. That did the job. I'll check your answer in some minutes when I'm allowed to.