# Webkit date parsing

Tags: javascript, parsing, webkit, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safari JS cannot parse YYYY-MM-DD date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085937/safari-js-cannot-parse-yyyy-mm-dd-date-format)

I have a simple function to calculate the amount of days between to dates.

```
function checkDias(){
    str1 = $('#salida').val();
    str2 = $('#regreso').val();
    difference = Math.floor(( Date.parse(str2) - Date.parse(str1) ) / 86400000);
    if (diferencia > 0) { } else {
        console.log(difference); console.log(str1); console.log(str2);
       // alert the user....
    }
}
```

I do this to check that the 2nd date is after the first one. In Firefox this works ok but in Webkit (Safari or Chrome) it doesn't. str1 and str2 log into the console just fine but the difference var in Webkit return NaN and in FF it returns the int value.

Any idea why this might be? I'm using a jQuery UI date widget to get and YYYY-MM-DD format but I don't think this has to do anything with it.

Thanks!

Comment: See: [Safari JS cannot parse YYYY-MM-DD date format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085937/safari-js-cannot-parse-yyyy-mm-dd-date-format/3085993#3085993)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small function fixes Date.parse for Webkit and IE:

https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601

I tested it and now Webkit and IE parse the dates as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The Date.parse method is inconsistent in my opinion (the actual format differs across various browsers, versions of JS engine etc.). I'm used to the following method to make various operations on dates in JavaScript (compare for example):

1. Get the components of the date somehow (in your case you can just split the string by '-').
2. Construct the date using components from the previous step.
3. Compare the unix timstamp of the dates using getTime() method.

Here is the code:

```
var d1Parts = s1.split('-'),
    d2Parts = s2.split('-'),
    d1 = new Date(d1Parts[0], d1Parts[1]-1, d1Parts[2]),
    d2 = new Date(d2Parts[0], d2Parts[1]-1, d2Parts[2]);

if ( d1.getTime() < d2.getTime() ) {
    console.log('the first date is before the second');
}
```

Comment: You need to subtract 1 on the month part, when calling the `Date` constructor, not to add (months are zero-based). Also to compare the timestamps, you don't need to explicitly call the `getTime` method, by comparing `if (d1 < d2)` the `<` operator will implicitly convert the two objects involved to primitive.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Christian.