# Javascript getTime since beginning of 2012 in miliseconds

Tags: javascript, object, date, time

`getTime()` gives you milliseconds since January 1, 1970.

How can I get the milliseconds since January 1, 2012?

This is what I currently have:

```
var n = new Date()
var a = n.getTime()

console.log (a)
```

Comment: You would need to be more specific, since 1/1/2012 00:00:00 GMT?

Comment: Just build an object which is the date since Jan 1st, 2012 at 00:00 and .getTime() on it, it is then just a matter of making a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ms = +new Date() - new Date( '2012/01/01' )
```

or make that 2nd date object `new Date( '2012/01/01 GMT' )` if desired

Comment: ?  That's your ms since 1/1/2012.  Do whatever you want with it

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I wanted

Comment: That date format is *not* the format that must be recognized by conforming implementations of ECMAScript Edition 5.1. The format that must be recognized is the extended format specified in ISO 8601 (see section 15.9.1.15). Also, as a feature of ECMAScript, the `-` operator converts all its operands to `Number` (section 11.6.2), so the explicit conversion with unary `+` is unnecessary: `var ms = new Date() - new Date("2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");`.

Comment: You must use UTC else the duration is timezone specific.

Comment: @PointedEars -- Every implementation of ECMAScript recognizes `YYYY/MM/DD`, there's no point in writing out the full format.  I'd sooner write ( YYYY, MM, DD ) as in matsev's answer.  @TJR -- hence the 2nd line

Comment: @cwolves Sufficient proof for your statement is lacking and cannot be provided, because you can only ever prove it for a *subset* of ECMAScript implementations.

Comment: @PointedEars -- And I care why?  ___Every___ version of IE, Safari, Chrome, FF, Opera, Mobile Safari, etc recognize `YYYY/MM/DD`.  As does node.js, rhino, asp (js), ...

Comment: @PointedEars -- Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085937/safari-js-cannot-parse-yyyy-mm-dd-date-format, not all ECMAScript implementations properly parse `ISO 8601`.  They ___all___ properly parse `YYYY/MM/DD`.  Guess which one I'm going to use?  The point is that I don't care whatsoever what specs say when specs can be incorrectly implemented.  I care what works.

Comment: @cwolves Your logic is flawed. QED.

Comment: The argument "P is standardized. Q is proprietary. P does not work in A and B. Q works in B and C. Therefore, I am using Q *instead of* P." is a fallacy. The conclusion "Therefore, you are using and recommending *only* P." is a fallacy as well, as evidenced by my answer.

Comment: My argument is that B and C are real where A is imaginary.  REAL WORLD.  Sheesh

Comment: @PointedEars -- let me make this simple.  Show me a JS engine where `YYYY/MM/DD` does _not_ work and I'll change my mind.  Until then, I've shown you one where `ISO 8601` does _not_ work so your argument boils down to "Theory is more important than results" which is absurd and makes your argument invalid.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
var diff = new Date() - new Date(2012, 0, 1); // diff is in milliseconds
```

for calculating differences including local time zone deviations, or

```
var diff = new Date() - Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1); // diff in ms
```

for more scientific solutions.

Note that months in Javascript are zero based.

Comment: The `Date` constructor will create an object with a time value that has an offset corresponding to the local time zone. The OP has clarified in the meantime that they want January  1, 2012 00:00 *GMT* instead.

Comment: Added a second example that uses UTC time.

Comment: I forgot about `Date.UTC()`. Very clever. Therefore, the best solution for me.

Comment: Not using Date.UTC will result in timezone specific durations. So the first example is error prone.

Comment: Updated the answer with a clarifying comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/56150009/html/SO8780297/example.htm

Sample output. Notice how the `DurationGMT` & `DurationLocal` are different. When doing comparisons with dates *always* use GMT.

```
Now:         1,326,054,979,124 ms (Sun, 08 Jan 2012 20:36:19 GMT)

Start1:      1,325,376,000,000 ms (Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 GMT)
Start2:      1,325,376,000,000 ms (Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 GMT)
Start3:      1,325,376,000,000 ms (Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 GMT)
DurationGMT: 678,979,124 ms (Accurate method)

StartLocal1:   1,325,397,600,000 ms (Sun, 01 Jan 2012 06:00:00 GMT)
DurationLocal: 657,379,124 ms !!! Don't use this method
```

Here are three methods to get a GMT date, #3 would be what you want.

```js
var now = new Date();
var startOfYear1 = createGMTDate1(2012, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var startOfYear2 = createGMTDate2(2012, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var startOfYear3 = createGMTDate3(2012, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var durationGMTMillis = now.getTime() - startOfYear1.getTime(); // accurate

var startOfYearLocal1 = new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var durationLocalMillis = now.getTime() - startOfYearLocal1.getTime(); // inaccurate

function createGMTDate1(year, month, date, hours, mins, secs, millis) {
  var dateDefaultTz = new Date(year, month, date, hours, mins, secs, millis);
  var localeTzGMTMillis = dateDefaultTz.getTime();
  var localeTzGMTOffsetMillis = dateDefaultTz.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
  var dateGMT = new Date(localeTzGMTMillis - localeTzGMTOffsetMillis);
  return dateGMT;
}

function createGMTDate2(year, month, date, hours, mins, secs, millis) {
  var dateGMT = new Date(0);
  dateGMT.setUTCFullYear(year);
  dateGMT.setUTCMonth(month);
  dateGMT.setUTCDate(date);
  dateGMT.setUTCHours(hours);
  dateGMT.setUTCMinutes(mins);
  dateGMT.setUTCSeconds(secs);
  dateGMT.setUTCMilliseconds(millis);
  return dateGMT;
}

function createGMTDate3(year, month, date, hours, mins, secs, millis) {
  var dateGMT = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, date, hours, mins, secs, millis));
  return dateGMT;
}
```

Comment: createGMTDate1() looks bogus. createGMTDate2() has too many calls.

Comment: @PointedEars, does it look bogus, or did you test it and it fails? Check out the link to execute the js.

Comment: Attempting to create a `Date` instance with a certain time value is *not* the same as computing a difference between time values.

Comment: @PointedEars, did you even read the answer? var durationMillis = now.getTime() - startOfYear1.getTime();

Comment: As I suspected, `createGMTDate1()` fails during the DST switch. That is a common mistake. `createGMTDate1()` returns "Sun Mar 27 2011 03:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)", while `Date.UTC()` when passed the same arguments returns the time value for "Sun Mar 27 2011 04:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)" in Chromium 16.0.912.63 (Developer Build 113337 Linux). [Testcase](http://PointedEars.de/scripts/test/date-utc)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the solution is subtracting `Date` instances:

```
var ms = now - before;
```

This works because the `-` operator converts its operands to `Number` ([ECMAScript Language Specification, Edition 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), section 11.6.2). The corresponding `ToNumber` algorithm checks if the object has a `valueOf` method, and calls it if it exists (sections 9.3, 9.1, and 8.12.8).

It now happens that the `Date.prototype.valueOf()` method, that `Date` instances inherit, returns the same value as `Date.prototype.getTime()` for a given `Date` instance (section 15.9.5.8). Which is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 (CE) 00:00:00.000 UTC ("epoch") (section 15.9.1.1).

The first operand is obvious if you want to compare against the local time:

```
var now = new Date();
```

The second part is a bit more tricky because you want to count from January 1, 2012 (CE) 00:00:00.000 *GMT*.  For that you *cannot* use

```
var before = new Date(2012, 0, 1);
```

(or variations thereof) because it uses 00:00:00.000 *local* time (section 15.9.3.1).  There are at least two ways to make this work:

1. Use a string value in a date format that must be recognized by conforming implementations of ECMAScript Edition 5.1 (section 15.9.1.15):

   ```
   var ms = new Date() - new Date("2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
   ```
2. If you are concerned about backwards compatibility, you can set the time explicitly (section 15.9.5):

   ```
   var before = new Date();
   before.setUTCFullYear(2012, 0, 1);
   before.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

   var ms = now - before;
   ```

Comment: You must use UTC else the duration is timezone specific.