# Issues with dates in JS across several browsers

Tags: javascript, date

One of my projects doesn't display some informations on safari while it does on chrome. After a few hours of searching, I found that the problem is related to how Safari implements `new Date()` & `Date.parse`.

I have some ideas one how to fix this (thanks to [Invalid date in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari) & [Safari JS cannot parse YYYY-MM-DD date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085937/safari-js-cannot-parse-yyyy-mm-dd-date-format)), but I was wondering if there is not a way to overload the Date object to fix this behaviour, while not breaking compatibility.

I'm a beginner in Js, so I don't know if there is a way to make the browser use the built-in functions if they work, or one I supply if not. For what it's worth, the projects is a rails 3.1 app with JQuery & Backbone.js

Thanks for your time!

--- **EDIT**

For what it's worth, I used [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to fix this.

Comment: FWIW, IE<9 has some issues too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* replace the `Date` function entirely if you like (`window.Date = ...`), or just `Date.parse` (`Date.parse = ...`), but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, use a function of your own that understands the format you're giving it, and have that function return a `Date` instance. If you are going to be running your code on implementations that don't yet support the [ECMAScript 5 date format](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15) (and there are still a *lot* of users using browsers that don't), you'll have to parse the date yourself.