# Date.prototype.getDay doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript

This script works perfectly in Chrome, but I get undefined in Safari. Do you know how to solve it?

```
var dateString = "2013-07-31 12:00:00";

var daysOfWeek = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
var whichDay = daysOfWeek[new Date(dateString).getDay()];

alert(whichDay);
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utn3yyzc/

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085937/safari-js-cannot-parse-yyyy-mm-dd-date-format . Safari probably can't convert dateString to a valid Date object, then you get undefined.

Comment: `console.log(new Date("2013-07-31 12:00:00"));` returns "Invalid Date"

Comment: When a JS program doesn't work as expected, the first thing you should do is check the browser console for error messages. That would have helped you understand the problem.

Comment: If you need to parse a non-standard date format, you should look into using moment.js.

Comment: Here's one with a workable date format: http://jsfiddle.net/gLr6z8a4/

Answer (score 2):

Let's check out what MDN has to say about sending a date-string into a `Date` constructor.

> ## MDN : Global Objects : [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
>
> ---
>
> ### Syntax
>
> > `new Date(dateString)`;
>
> #### Parameters
>
> **`dateString`**
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method ([IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and also a [version of ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)).
>
> > **Note:** parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse`, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to *browser differences and inconsistencies*.

We see that this method of parsing is unreliable and "strongly discouraged", so we must implement our own parsing or use a library that can do this for us.

---

### Manual Way

Simply parse the date from the given string.

```js
function parseDate(datestring) {
  var d = datestring.split(/\D+/g).map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 10); });
  return new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5]);
}

var dateString = "2013-07-31 12:00:00";
var daysOfWeek = [ 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];
var whichDay = daysOfWeek[parseDate(dateString).getDay()];

alert(whichDay);
```

### Library (MomentJS) Solution

```js
var whichDay = moment('2013-07-31 12:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('dddd');

alert(whichDay);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

## Update

Here is a modern version that used i18n:

```js
const
  parseDate = (datestring) => 
    (([year, month, date, hour, minute, second]) =>
      new Date(year, month - 1, date, hour, minute, second))
    (datestring.split(/\D+/g).map(v => parseInt(v, 10))),
  dateString = '2013-07-31 12:00:00',
  whichDay = parseDate(dateString)
    .toLocaleString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });

console.log(whichDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date(dateString)` returns an invalid date.

I'd suggest parsing your date string in a more explicit way (Safari seems to not support this format).

For instance:

```
var dateString = "2013-07-31 12:00:00";

var split = dateString.split(' ');
var dateSplit = split[0].split('-');
var hourSplit = split[1].split(':');

var d = new Date(dateSplit[0], dateSplit[1] - 1, dateSplit[2],     hourSplit[0], hourSplit[1], hourSplit[2]);
```