# Parse and format date in string

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'm trying out [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) v2.

I want to format a date in a string by using the [`toDate`](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.8/docs/format) and [`format`](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.8/docs/format) functions:

```
import { format, toDate } from 'date-fns'
format(toDate('2019-02-11T14:00:00'), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

But get the following error:

> RangeError: Invalid time value

Comment: What are those functions (`format()` and `toDate()`) supposed to be, or really where do they come from? Those are not standard JavaScript.

Comment: Where's the `toDate()` coming from? Check the syntax. I thought it should be `format(toDate('2019-02-11T14:00:00'), 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss')`

Comment: date-fns has a `parse` function but no `toDate` function

Comment: @phuzi The new 2.0 alpha version has a toDate() function. https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.26/docs/toDate

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It seems that you are using Version 2.0 of date-fns, which is still in alpha (development) status currently.

What functions are available and how they work still seems to change frequently. For example, while in version v2.0.0-alpha.26 `toDate()` [can handle string parameters](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.26/docs/toDate), it [cannot do that any longer](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.27/docs/toDate) in version v2.0.0-alpha.27. There is a new [`parseISO()`](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.27/docs/parseISO) function instead.

This should work now:

```
format(parseISO('2019-02-11T14:00:00'), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

However, while version 2 is still in beta, I would suggest using the stable version 1.x for now.

Comment: In fact, I would suggest not using the library at all. Introducing all those breaking changes going from version 1 to version 2 and again completely changing the interface multiple times while developing version 2 means they will probably introduce further breaking changes in the future...

Comment: I have to agree on you. But in comparison to moment.js, date-fns is fast and lighter.

Answer (score 17):

**date-fns 2.0.0-alpha.27 (demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tztuz6)**

Use [parseISO](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.27/docs/parseISO):

```
import { format, parseISO } from 'date-fns'
const formattedDate = format(parseISO('2019-02-11T14:00:00'), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

---

**date-fns v1.30.1 (demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mt3y6p)**

Use [parse](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/parse):

```
import { format, parse } from 'date-fns'
const formattedDate = format(parse('2019-02-11T14:00:00'), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: The parse() in 2.x works different than in 1.x. In 2.x it now always requires a second parameter for specifying to format to understand.

Comment: @NineBerry I updated my answer. It works now for 1.x and 2.x.

Comment: parse requires 3 necessary arguments now: https://date-fns.org/v2.26.0/docs/parse.
````parse( "22/11/2021", "dd/MM/yyyy", new Date() )````

Answer (score 11):

Btw, one more case to validate:

```js
import { isValid, parseISO, parse } from 'date-fns'

// Date valid
if (isValid(parseISO('2019-11-27 09:45:00'))) {
 let dt = parse('2019-11-27 09:45:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', new Date())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method toDate is not able to read that format.

Try to convert to Date lke this:

```
var date = new Date('2019-02-11T14:00:00')
```

Comment: Downvoted because attempting to do this is what made me look into  date-fns  in the first place - this was exactly the format that Safari threw an "Invalid date" error on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085937/safari-js-cannot-parse-yyyy-mm-dd-date-format

Comment: `1990-04-20T17:47:38.000000Z` this is a valid time string, here time zone data is included in it.