# How to validate date input in 3 fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I have 3 fields for date input:

```
<input type="text" id="passport-doi-1" name="passport-doi-1" placeholder="DD" maxlength="2">
<input type="text" id="passport-doi-2" name="passport-doi-2" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2">
<input type="text" id="passport-doi-3" name="passport-doi-3" placeholder="YYYY" maxlength="4">
```

How should I validate with jQuery Validate plugin that if date is input, then this is correct?

Looks like I should create `groups` of fields (to have only one error message) and then custom validation rule. But how it should look like?

**Upd**. I've tried to do the following, but it doesn't work:

```
$.validator.addMethod('validDate', function (value, element) {
  var dd = $("#passport-doi-dd").val();
  var mm = $("#passport-doi-mm").val();
  var yyyy = $("#passport-doi-yyyy").val();
  if (dd=="" && mm=="" && yyyy=="") return true;
  try {
    var date = new Date(yyyy,mm-1,dd,0,0,0,0);
    return mm===(date.getMonth()+1) && dd===date.getDate() && yyyy===date.getFullYear();
  }
  catch(er) {
    return false;
  }
}, 'Please use format DD MM YYYY.');

  ...
  rules: {
    "passport-doi-dd": {
      required: false,
      validDate: true,
      range: [1, 31]
    }, 
    "passport-doi-mm": {
      required: false,
      validDate: true,
      range: [1, 12]
    }, 
    "passport-doi-yyyy": {
      required: false,
      validDate: true,
      range: [1990, 2012]
    }
  },
  messages: {
    "passport-doi-dd": "Please use format DD MM YYYY.",
    "passport-doi-mm": "Please use format DD MM YYYY.",
    "passport-doi-yyyy": "Please use format DD MM YYYY."
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track-- You need to pass the `Date` constructor numbers instead of strings (`val` will return strings). You can also leverage the `params` argument to your custom rule to make it a bit more extensible (not specific to three fields with specific `id`s):

```
$.validator.addMethod("multidate", function (value, element, params) {
  var daySelector = params[0]
      , monthSelector = params[1]
      , yearSelector = params[2]
      , day = parseInt($(daySelector).val(), 10)
      , month = parseInt($(monthSelector).val(), 10)
      , year = parseInt($(yearSelector).val(), 10)
      , date = new Date(year, month, day);

  return (!$(daySelector).val() && !$(monthSelector).val() && !$(yearSelector).val()) || 
    !isNaN(date.getTime());

});


$(document).ready(function () {
  var dateFields = ["#passport-doi-1", "#passport-doi-2", "#passport-doi-3"];
  $("#dateform").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "#errors",
    groups: {
      date: dateFields.join("")
    },
    rules: {
      "passport-doi-1": {
        multidate: dateFields
      },
      "passport-doi-2": {
        multidate: dateFields
      },
      "passport-doi-3": {
        multidate: dateFields
      }
    },
    messages: {
      "passport-doi-1": {
        multidate: "Please enter a valid date"
      },
      "passport-doi-2": {
        multidate: "Please enter a valid date"
      },
      "passport-doi-3": {
        multidate: "Please enter a valid date"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I *think* the `group` option is only for grouping *error messages* (so you still have to define validation rules for each input).

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/oqawaz/9

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Is there any way to refer to `groups` instead of `dateFields` creation and usage?

Comment: @LA_: An easy way to do this would be to use the same array in `dateFields` and in assigning the `groups` property --see my updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, found one bug with this code - if user input day and month, but hasn't input year, then it is treated as valid (since year element is optional), but it shouldn't be - either full date or nothing.

Comment: Yes, it is OK now. I've also added `range: [1930, 2012]` to the year field, otherwise even `1` was accepted.

Comment: just now I've noticed that it accepts wrong dates like 33/13/2000. Looks like `!isNaN(date.getTime()` is incorrect way to verify dates - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066005/how-to-allow-user-to-input-not-full-date-for-ex-without-date-and-month

Comment: @LA_: It looks like validating whether an object is a date or not is not all that trivial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript

Comment: @LA_: Typo in `dateFields.join("")`. It must be `dateFields.join(" ")` (a space is missing)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098202/javascript-detecting-valid-dates if you want validation that also filters out dates like "february 31"