# How to validate entered date format is valid or not?

Tags: javascript

**How to check entered date format is valid or not in text box $("#txtCustomDate").**

```
function datVal(){
  var obj = $("#txtCustomDate").val();
  var format = obj.toUpperCase();
  var date = new Date();
  text = moment(date).format(format);
  $('#editor').val(value + "<span>" + text + "</span>");
}
```

Comment: here is the solution please check... [Valid Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8098359/4018240)

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala I think the question is to check if provided string is a valid date format pattern, not if it is a date in valid format, i.e. the string `"mm-dd-yyyy"` makes sense as a date format, but `"mmm-uu-abc"` does not.

Comment: The idea to try and format a date using the provided string makes sense. Problem is moment.js will just print the tokens it doesn't recognize as formatting patterns, for example `moment().format("WTF MAN")` will happily substitute the `W` for week number, leave the `TF` as is, then `3` for `M` (month), `PM` for `A` (AM/PM), then `N` as-is. So you'll get something like `"11TF 3PMN"` because the format pattern was kind of valid, at least for the library.

Comment: Your question should include how you've attempted to solve the issue, what you expect as output and what you are getting, along with any error messages. Whether a date format string is valid or not depends entirely on the tokens that your parser recognises.

Comment: First of all you need to narrow down what you consider valid and invalid pattern.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var dateExp= /^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-.\/])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$/;
if(dateExp.test('17-03-2016'))
{
 alert('Valid Format');
}
else
{
 alert('Invalid Format');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any explanation? How would you use it to validate date format strings?

Comment: Code-only answers are not helpful, you should explain the OP's issue, how to fix it and how your code can help.

Comment: Suppose User enter DD/MMMMMMMMM/Y ,then it is wrong format,so it should give error.

Comment: Dear @pawel please visit [Link1](http://bit.ly/22nhtFd) and [Link2](http://regexr.com/3d1ek) for details.

Comment: @jayeshpatil well, is it really wrong? moment.js won't reject it, it will print `""17/MarchMarch3/2016"` which is maybe stupid, but not technically wrong.

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala yeah I get what this regex does, but it doesn't apply to this question (which is not about dates, but date format expressions). Or if it does you should include an explanation in your answer.