# How to validate for existed date with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datepicker

Currently I had problem to validate date of the forms page.

I use date picker form input.

But when user sets date manually (input by keyboard), that date picker still allows wrong dates such as 2016-02-31 (which not existed).
Date picker never complains about that.

So how can I validate a date(string) with jQuery or javascript?

Comment: this solution solved my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098202/javascript-detecting-valid-dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

2016-02-31 is handled as 2016-03-02, so you just have to compare, whether the date string is equal to the input.

Comment: it's too manual, i think there is better way to validate date.