# valid date is coming as output from invalida date Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I am unable to understand why javascript is giving valid date equals to **1 dec**  date when giving invalid date? Is this behaviour incorporated in language for specific reason? because it must be invalid date for my use case
**new Date("11/31/2017")**

Comment: I've never been able to learn all the rules and exceptions of the Date constructor parser. Are you positively sure that it should always reject dates in American format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098202/javascript-detecting-valid-dates

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is not designed to validate input, or even to be picky. On the contrary, it's explicitly designed to create an instance at any cost, with creative rules like this:

> Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if
> values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as
> the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will
> be adjusted. E.g. new Date(2013, 13, 1) is equivalent to new
> Date(2014, 1, 1)

So if you really need to validate dates you need to look somewhere else.

As about `11/31/2017`, the constructor expects this:

> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format
> recognized by the [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method ([IETF-compliant RFC 2822
> timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and also a version of [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)).

... which looks good. But this follows (emphasis mine):

> parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse,
> they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to **browser
> differences and inconsistencies**.

And if we dig into `Date.parse()` docs we finally read this:

> The ECMAScript specification states: If the String does not conform to
> the standard format the function may fall back to any
> implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing
> algorithm. Unrecognizable strings or dates containing illegal element
> values in ISO formatted strings shall cause Date.parse() to return
> NaN.
>
> However, invalid values in date strings not recognized as ISO format
> as defined by ECMA-262 may or may not result in NaN, depending on the
> browser and values provided, e.g.:
>
> ```
> // Non-ISO string with invalid date values
> new Date('23/25/2014');
> ```
>
> will be treated as a local date of 25 November, 2015 in Firefox 30 and
> an invalid date in Safari 7

This fallback case is the one your date fell into.