# Date.parse() false positives

Tags: javascript, date

In code below, I don't want the string `not_a_date` to be whitelisted as a proper date, but rather as `NaN` or `invalid date`. but `Date.parse` returns a proper epoch value.

```
not_a_date = 'https://www.example.com/2021/03/03'
Date.parse(not_a_date)
// Expected: NaN
// Result: 1614709800000
```

- Not looking for a exact format match, but a fuzzy match that still works the same as `Date.parse` for other cases such as `2020.01.01`, `01/10/2020`
- Another function that achieves this also works for me.

Comment: Can't you use a regex to validate date format?

Comment: Yes, regex also works but I'm keeping regex as the last resort, as there are lot of combinations for valid date format. If there's a native method that invalidates cases with dangling prefix & suffix

Comment: Your question is way too vague to expect a useful answer. The behaviour of built–in parsers is almost completely implementation dependent, adding another set of heuristics on top doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: See [*Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript), [*JavaScript Detecting Valid Dates*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098202/javascript-detecting-valid-dates) and [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Thanks for the links. yeah I agree its a vague question. just looking out if a more stricter version of parse is provided by API (shouldve mentioned this in question) before going with custom validator for my usecase.

Answer (score 2):

Date.parse is still largely dependant on the browser you're using; your code DOES return NaN in Firefox v94 for example. You'll likely have to write your own parsing function before passing it to Date.parse().

Comment: If the OP parses the string (either with a bespoke function or library), then there's no need to use Date.parse, which should not be used for any string other than the two formats supported by ECMA-262 (and even then it's problematic).

Comment: I was thinking more that he would check to see if it is one of those valid strings before parsing it to Date.parse, rather than parsing it into a date themselves, sorry!

Comment: So… parse a string to another string to pass to another parser that is implementation dependent. Hmmm.