# Detect if string can be converted to date

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

At the moment, i am using:

```
var d = new Date("March 7 2012");
document.write(d.getMonth() + 1);
```

What if the date string is something weird like `No Date` i.e:

```
var d = new Date("No Date"); // anything which isn't recognisable as a date
document.write(d.getMonth() + 1);
```

Here the output I get is `NaN`

How do I display a better message if something like this happens

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check that the value is not `NaN` by using `isNaN`:

```
    if (isNaN(d.getMonth())) {
       //value is not a date
    }
    else
    {
       document.write(d.getMonth() + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use somthing like this

```
var d= new Date('No Date');
    var mon=d.getMonth()+1;
    document.write(isNAN(mon)?"No Date": mon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
Date.isValid = function(date) { 
  return !!Date.parse(date);
};

Date.isValid('fake') // false
Date.isValid('1990-11-15T00:00:00+00:00') // true
```

Answer (score -3):

This seemed to work.

```
 new Date("Hi") == 'Invalid Date'
```

Comment: down vote because this doesn't work? down vote because it is not accurate all the time? or just because you wanted to down vote some one?