# Why does Chrome Dev Tool show a dates __proto__ as Invalid Date?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I know `__proto__` is deprecated (or not part of the standard) and all that but I'm still curious as to what it means when it says Invalid Date when I look at the `__proto__` value of..

```
var myDate = new Date(1331869050000);
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> *"I'm still curious as to what it means when it says Invalid Date"*

That's simply the `toString` value of the `prototype` object of the `Date` constructor function.

---

```
Date.prototype.toString(); // "Invalid Date"
```

---

You can override it if you like...

```
Date.prototype.toString = function() { return "I like turtles." };

var myDate = new Date(1331869050000);
myDate.__proto__; // I like turtles.
```

---

A little off topic, but `__proto__` is in the current working draft for the next version of ECMAScript, codename Harmony.

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts

> - Added section B.3.1 with specifies `__proto__` feature.

Comment: You are close, but the "why" part is still missing, the reason is that the [`Date.prototype`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5) object is a *Date object by itself* but its `[[PrimitiveValue]]` internal property is `NaN` (this internal property on date objects stores the [time value](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.1)), so it doesn't represent actually a valid date. `Date.prototype` is an object similar to `new Date(NaN)`...

Comment: @CMS: Makes sense. That's good info. Feel free to add it to the answer if you'd like.

Comment: so basically, there is no error and Chrome is just reflecting the toString() which doesn't show the true value

Comment: Plus one for the love of turtles

Answer (score 2):

considering you made a new Date object, I wouldn't worry about it. The reason being, if you try this code:

```
var myDate = new Date(1331869050000);
alert(typeof myDate.getMonth != 'undefined')    //true
```

This will determine that you are inheriting the Date objects methods and that in fact, Date IS defined.

If you would like further investigation, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript) post.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of a Date instance has no defined value. Only the instance has a value. You define it when you instantiate it.