# Why am I getting "Invalid Date" from Date.prototype?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Chrome Dev Tool show a dates __proto__ as Invalid Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725299/why-does-chrome-dev-tool-show-a-dates-proto-as-invalid-date)

I get a weird message when I look up the prototype of the `Date` object:

```
Date.prototype; // Invalid Date
```

This is strange; why am I not getting the object from the prototype of `Date` as expected? Furthermore, the message that it returns is a string, but `typeof(Date.prototype)` returns "object". I also find that peculiar. Why am I getting this output?

Comment: How are you _"getting"_ the value of `Date.prototype`? Are you doing an implicit `toString` conversion?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I'm simply logging it to the console.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Did you try it? If you `alert` it, you get "Invalid Date", if you `console.log` it, you get `Date {Invalid Date}`

Comment: In that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725299/why-does-chrome-dev-tool-show-a-dates-proto-as-invalid-date

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and in Chrome it said "Invalid Date". When I alert it, it says also "Invalid Date". I guess it varies from browser to browser

Comment: `Date.prototype.toString()` is called in this case.

Comment: What it shows when you alert it is (afaik) always the result of calling `toString` on it. What you see in the console depends on how fancy the browser maker got in his console features. @Antony `NaN` is the internal value of the date object, which is returned by `valueOf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **15.9.5 Properties of the Date Prototype Object**
>
> The Date prototype object is itself a Date object (its [[Class]] is "Date") whose
> [[PrimitiveValue]] is NaN.

NaN is what's happening