# showing in jquery invalid date?

Tags: c#, jquery, var, invalidation, onrender

```
$(function () {
    debugger;
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var checkin = $('#_startdate').datepicker({
        language: 'en-US',
        onRender: function (date) {
            debugger;
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            checkout.setValue(newDate);
        }
        checkin.hide();
        $('#_enddate')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');

    var checkout = $('#_enddate').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        checkout.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
});
```

I am trying to run this code but, `var nowTemp = new Date();` shows an invalid date and I don't know why? Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by invalid date? Are you being confused by the full date string which shows the UTC date?

Comment: what is the output of the wrong date you are seeing? .. can you post it to your question so we can see what the wrong date looks like?

Comment: i am getting Date.prototype; // Invalid Date

Comment: please can anybody tell me the reason why the prototype: is showing invalid date. is there any problem with my system date format?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty date with new Date()

If you want the current date you can use $.now()

Comment: no i m getting '1382713456852' this value in var by using var a=$.now()

Answer (score 0):

nothing to worry about.
But if you want the actual reason, look at the CMS note on this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725453/2143734

Comment: thanks man, but by this i can't solve my prob...can u please tell me a simple solution because i m new to jquery thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a date picker (https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker ?) but you did not say what is your actual problem doing so. As I said, the "invalid date" thing you get at the beginning cannot trigger a functional problem.

Comment: i am following [link](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) this tutorial check in and check out but not getting the proper result

Comment: the simple datepicker is working fine but i am not able to hide the past dates. then i put a debugger on the top of my code, and i have seen this when i the process reached at 'var nowTemp = new Date();' i am getting date in format like 'Fir 08 10' but i am also getting invalid date in prototype

Comment: this is exactly what i want. thanks dude. i will try this code if then i will let u know, dose it work or ? ;)

Comment: Sure, but this code is not mine ;) all the credit goes to this guy : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8356601/2143734

Comment: no  its not working. dates not hiding, i am getting `var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({` undefined in `dates`

Comment: in `var dateToday = new Date();` i am getting the value `Fri Oct 25 21:47:57 UTC+0530 2013` but when when i inspect it with `debugger` and expend the `+` i got `[prototype] invalid date` :(

Comment: Well, as I said, you cannot make any assumption that this particular Invalid Date thing on the prototype. As long as you have an actual date in the value, do not worry about the prototype part display. However, I do not understand the "dates not hiding". Did you start from the code within the fiddle ? Because this one does hide dates previous to today, right ?