# JavaScript date object in a nested array become "Invalid Date"

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

The following:

```
var pointDate = new Date(2009, 00, 01);
var pointSingle = [pointDate,1000];
var pointDataset = [pointSingle];
console.log(pointDate);
console.log(pointSingle);
console.log(pointDataset);
```

Displays this:

```
Thu Jan 01 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
[Thu Jan 01 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), 1000]
[Array[2]]
0: Array[2]
0: Invalid Date
1: 1000
length: 2
```

Does anyone know why the date object becomes and invalid date after be entered into a nested array?

Thanks

Update 1: I tested the same code snippet in a new HTML file, and the issue did not manifest. I don't know why...

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725299/why-does-chrome-dev-tool-show-a-dates-proto-as-invalid-date

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. What browser are you testing this on?

Comment: I am testing using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m

Answer (score 1):

Working correctly on chrome. This is the code :

```
var pointDate = new Date(2009, 00, 01);
var pointSingle = [pointDate,1000];
var pointDataset = [pointSingle];
console.log(pointDate);
console.log(pointSingle);
console.log(pointDataset);
// added to debug - but before this also the values were valid ones.
console.log(pointDataset[0]);
```

[image]

**ADD**

It seems the nested arrays are treated as objects but not arrays at all. Somehow, it is not yet correctly understood of this kind of behavior.

Comment: I am also using Chrome. I edited my code to include console.log(pointDataset[0]); and it correctly displays the date object, just like your code. Problem still persists.

Comment: Others have suggested [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725299/why-does-chrome-dev-tool-show-a-dates-proto-as-invalid-date). Even though the data contains, since __proto__ is deprecated, it says Invalid Date... also, there is good explanation of something like `date(NAN)`...