# regular expression pattern error

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use a javascript regular expression to validate date of birth textbox. here is my code

```
var patt=/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}/;
alert(patt.test("1985/08/03"));
```

and the error said: SyntaxEror: Unexpected token {

I don't understand why, this pattern works fine in the asp.net RegularExpressionValidator controller. 
Many thanks

Comment: I hope you are not doing anything international or at least specyfying the desired format, because otherwise a date might be '2012-11-13' or '20.10.2012' or some such.

Comment: i used a datepicker and the format is fixed, but i assume some people will type something in, so I use RE to validate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` characters, otherwise the interpreter sees the first one and thinks  that's the end of the regexp.

You should also put anchors in your regexp to ensure it matches the *whole* string, and doesn't match any string which happens to *contain* that pattern.

For brevity you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, too:

```
var patt = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
```

NB: your sample doesn't work - you've put the year first, but the RE is expecting it to be last.

Comment: i just want to use the sample to test the RE, but thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Here a sample code that **really** validate a date in JavaScript  :

```
function isValidDate(dateStr) {
    s = dateStr.split('/');
    d = new Date(+s[2], s[1]-1, +s[0]);
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === "[object Date]") {
        if (!isNaN(d.getTime()) && d.getDate() == s[0] && 
            d.getMonth() == (s[1] - 1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

See [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not escaping the / separators in the pattern. Try

```
/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/;
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex (after you fix the non-escaped '/') will only check for the right number of digits.
It will not check if the month is between 1 and 12, the days between 1 and 31, or 30, or 28, or 29 depending on the month and leap years.

If that's enough for you, the closest you can get with regex is (assuming dd/mm/yyyy):

`/(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])\/(1[012]|0?[1-9])\/([12][0-9]{3})/`

Days will be in the range 1-31
Month will be in the range 1-12
I took the liberty to restrict the years from 1000 to 2999, but you can catch the format, if you want to restrict from 1970 to 2059 use `(19[789][0-9]|20[0-5][0-9])` on the year part.
And you'll get the day on $1, the month on $2 and the year on $3 (I think)