# After running the script spreadsheet functions get deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am new to the `Google` script. And I have not much knowledge from other codes. 
Still, I wish I had a script to export my schedule from a `Spreadsheet` to `Google Calendar`. I've been able to create a script based on this topic:
     [Create Google Calendar Events from Spreadsheet but prevent duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788897/create-google-calendar-events-from-spreadsheet-but-prevent-duplicates/15790894#15790894)

The only problem is that my functions I've made in my `spreadsheet` disappear when I run the script. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that getValues() doesn't get formulas, only their result, you need getFormulas() also, but this one doesn't get the values only cells.
Solution: before starting everything, merge up the formulas and values into a single var, as such:

```
var data = range.getValues();    
var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  for( line in data )
    for( column in data[i] )
      if( formulas[ line ][ column ] != '' )
        data[ line ][ column ] = formulas[ line ][ column ];
```

And only then proceed with the normal `for(i in...)`.

Comment: @JanVerhoeven if this solved you problem please mark as Answered just below the down arrow, if this question was well explained, upvote it in the up arrow.

Comment: @Kriggs I've always struggled writing both formula and values at the same time. I'll have to have a play with the code above and see what I can get working. If you do have a bit of time free, I'd really appreciate your comments on how your answer works. I get that it's reading both formula & values. But then how to use next. How to decide to write a formula or value. As I don't Fully understand the source script of this question, your answer is a little out of context for me (if that makes sense, nothing to do with your answer, just my understanding)

Comment: @Munkey getFormulas() return an Array just as getValues(), same size, but when there's no formula in the cell, it returns an empty String `''`. I just checked for when there's a formula (ie. not empty), I'll use it by placing that formula in the getValues() original Array. The above 2 fors are just to iterate all the 2 dimensions of the Array.