# Get active row inside Array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this Google Apps Script to read rows from a Google Spreadsheet but I need to find out the row number of the active array element.

The goal is to check if a row has been processed or not (`statusverwerkt` variable). If the value of `statusverwerkt` is `x` I create a Google event in the calendar and I want to change to value of `statusverwerkt` to `yes`

There might be another way to do this, but it would be helpful to find out the current row in the array element.

This is my code:

```js
function caltest1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  var Totalrows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var TotalNumrows = Totalrows.getNumRows();
  var Reservations = range-1;
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = Reservations;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 17);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var title = row[2];  // First column
    var desc = row[7];       // Second column
    var tstart = row[9];
    var tstop = row[10];
    var loc = row[3];

    var statusverwerkt = row[14]; 

    if (statusverwerkt = "x"){

    cal.createEvent(title, new Date(tstart), new Date(tstop), {description:desc,location:loc});

    //set statusverwerkt value = "yes"


    }
    else {

   // statusverwerkt = "x"
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to have come from [this blog](http://blog.ouseful.info/2010/03/04/maintaining-google-calendars-from-a-google-spreadsheet/) by Tony Hirst.

You'll find an updated version of it in [Create Google Calendar Events from Spreadsheet but prevent duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788897/create-google-calendar-events-from-spreadsheet-but-prevent-duplicates/15790894#15790894), which records the event ID to both remember which row has been processed as well as to provide a link back to the calendar event.

Instead of calculating the individual spreadsheet row, it records all updates in the `data` array, and then updates the spreadsheet in a single operation. This is faster then many writes, with the risk that the script could get interrupted for exceeding the 6 minute execution limit before updating the sheet.

Comment: I used the code as in your answer and it really helped me!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the row number is readily available by adding 1 to i.

For example, as you loop over the Array of spreadsheet rows you could do:

```
for (i in data) {
    var row_number = i+1;
```

The reason for the +1 is that the Array is zero indexed (starts counting at row 0), while the Google Spreadsheet functions start counting at row 1.

Comment: I only start processing from row 2. I tried the code anyway and converted row_number to a number. Then I try following code: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Q',row_number).setValue('verwerkt');` and get error _Cannot convert Q to (class). (line 40, file "ScriptCalendar")_

Comment: If you are starting your data at row 2 in the spreadsheet, you'll need to add 2 to i. Row 0 in your Array is row 2 in your spreadsheet.     In your comment, you are not using getRange() correctly. You can either pass a single String value EG `getRange('A2') //row 2, column A`or you can pass two numeric values, one for the row and one for the column:  `getRange(2,1)  //row 2, column 1` . Personally I prefer the latter one because you can just work with numbers, but if you prefer to use "A1" notation, you need to join the row number to your string:  `getRange('Q'+row_number);`