# Google Apps Script: event.setTime error and time format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm creating something of a booking system which is nearly complete. Currently I'm collecting data from a form, passing it to a sheet, and then using some of that info to create a calendar event. This all works fine.

On creating the event, I'm also collecting the eventID so that I can use it to identify the event and update it from the spreadsheet. These updates are also working, with the exception of updating the start/end date and time which causes the following error:

TypeError: Cannot find function setTime in object CalendarEventSeries.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
var eventStart =  sh.getRange("D"+rowNumber).getValues();
var eventEnd =  sh.getRange("E"+rowNumber).getValues();
event.setTime(eventStart, eventEnd);
```

I'm doing exactly the same thing with setLocation and setTitle without a problem.

I'm new to this, I don't know what an object is and so the error message means very little to me! But I can see that setTime is a method outlined in the class 'CalendarEvent' (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setTime(Date,Date)), but not in 'CalendarEventSeries'. All my events are on-off events anyway?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

**UPDATE**

I have integrated Mogsdad's Advanced Calendar Service code, and after

`"var endTime = parseDate(event.end.date||event.end.dateTime);"`

I am checking/logging 'startTime' and 'event'. 'startTime' is coming back as 'invalid date' (bad thing?) and 'event' is coming back with all the calendar entry info I can imagine (good thing I hope?!).

Where should the parseDate function actually go? Maybe I have it in the wrong place (I've tried it all over the place!) and this isn't being used?

Also, now the event I want to edit has been identified, are the dates parsed and used to search for the event I have already found in order to return a Calendar event that I can ultimately use setTime on? Is that the whole point of this?

Thanks for bearing with me.

**UPDATE 2 - INVALID DATE?**

If I skip the parsing and log the variable like this:

var startTime = event.start.dateTime;

The result is 2015-05-24T02:00:00+01:00 which I think is spot on. So the invalid date is definitely a case of something going wrong during the parse function as it only then that it returns 'invalid date'.

Code in context below.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Create Event Document Manually", functionName: "addSheet"},{name: "Update Calendar Entry", functionName: "getEventById"}
  ];


  ss.addMenu("Select Row & Click Here", menuEntries);
}



/**
 * Retrieve a CalendarApp CalendarEvent object from IDs.
 * This version utilizes the Advanced Calendar Service, which must be
 * enabled before use.
 *
 * @param {string} calendarId   ID of calendar to be searched
 * @param {string} eventId      Event ID to match
 *
 * @returns {CalendarEvent}     CalendarApp CalendarEvent object or null
 */


function getEventById(calendarId, eventId) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rowNumber = sh.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var myEventId = "q8q533oioluipirksmno88qv2g";
  var calendarId = "mydomain.tv_q9608ku2min78rasgt2s2n233c@group.calendar.google.com";


  // Get event by ID.
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, myEventId);
  // This isn't a CalendarApp CalendarEvent though, so use the info
  // in the event to find it AGAIN as the right type.




  // Get start & end times of event. All-day events start at start.date,
  // while other events start at start.datetime. Likewise for end.

  var startTime = parseDate(event.start.date||event.start.dateTime);
  var endTime = parseDate(event.end.date||event.end.dateTime);



   Logger.log('Variables: ' + startTime + ' and ' + endTime);

  // Get array of events that fall between startTime & endTime
  var calEvents = CalendarApp.getEvents(startTime, endTime);

  // Search through those events, looking for a match by ID
  for (var i=0; i<calEvents.length; i++) {
    var curId = calEvents[i].getId().split('@')[0];  // extract id from id@calendar.google.com
    if (curId == eventId) {
      // Mission accomplished; we have an Event object with given id!
      return calEvents[i];

    }
  }
  // We did not find matching event
  return null;


}




  function parseDate(string) {
  var parts = string.split('T');
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/-/g, '/');
  return new Date(parts.join(' '));
}
```

Comment: Yes, the edited update is right. That's a way to get the right event object.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for clarifying Serge. This feels like progress!

When I log 'event', this is the data I receive regarding the start date/time: "start":{"dateTime":"2015-05-24T02:00:00+01:00","timeZone":"Europe/London"}, 
Is this as expected and is there any reason why this wouldn't parse and cause the invalid date?

Comment: The helper function Mogsdad writes below ( parseDate(string)) deals with that format, it splits the string on the letter "T", takes the first part only and replaces hyphens by "/" so that the format is usable as an argument for the new Date statement. You shouldn't get an error there.

Comment: Indeed, I can see what the function is doing and why it's necessary, but in this case I really don't know if it's doing it or not. If the date is formatted incorrectly, before or after it was parsed, I would still expect to see it instead of 'invalid date' when I log the startTime/endTime variables, no? What is deciding the date is invalid? Invalid for what?! I'm not trying to do anything with it yet!

I will post my code in it's entirety to the original post, it's likely a stupid mistake on my part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serge has it right - the problem is that you've retrieved a [`CalendarEventSeries`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series) object, not a [`CalendarEvent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event). Since the only method in the service that will look for an event by ID is [`getEventSeriesById(iCalId)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEventSeriesById(String)), you're kinda stuck.

One option is to use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) instead:

```js
var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);
```

For new code, that's a great option, especially for developers already used to Javascript APIs. If you're a beginner or not familiar with the Advanced Services, though, you'll find that there's a steeper learning curve than for the Calendar Service.

In that case, these utilities should help you stick with the CalendarApp and its Classes and Methods, by filling the need for a `getEventById()` function.

#### Advanced Calendar Service under the hood

There are two versions of `getEventById()`. This first one utilizes the Advanced Calendar Service, which must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). The code is fairly straight-forward. You must provide the Calendar ID explicitly, since this isn't a Class Method. Example:

```js
var calendarId = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getId();
var eventId = "smmd8h1dfe9lo9bip52hidnqk0";
var event = getEventById(calendarId, eventId);
```

Code:

```js
/**
 * Retrieve a CalendarApp CalendarEvent object from IDs.
 * This version utilizes the Advanced Calendar Service, which must be
 * enabled before use.
 *
 * @param {string} calendarId   ID of calendar to be searched
 * @param {string} eventId      Event ID to match
 *
 * @returns {CalendarEvent}     CalendarApp CalendarEvent object or null
 */
function getEventById(calendarId, eventId) {
  // Get event by ID.
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);
  // This isn't a CalendarApp CalendarEvent though, so use the info
  // in the event to find it AGAIN as the right type.

  // Get start & end times of event. All-day events start at start.date,
  // while other events start at start.datetime. Likewise for end.
  var startTime = parseDate(event.start.date||event.start.dateTime);
  var endTime = parseDate(event.end.date||event.end.dateTime);

  // Get array of events that fall between startTime & endTime
  var calEvents = CalendarApp.getEvents(startTime, endTime);

  // Search through those events, looking for a match by ID
  for (var i=0; i<calEvents.length; i++) {
    var curId = calEvents[i].getId().split('@')[0];  // extract id from id@calendar.google.com
    if (curId == eventId) {
      // Mission accomplished; we have an Event object with given id!
      return calEvents[i];
    }
  }
  // We did not find matching event
  return null;
}
```

#### Calendar API via UrlFetchApp

This version utilizes the Calendar API via UrlFetchApp, which doesn't require any special enablement. However, the code is more complex than the previous version.

```js
/**
 * Retrieve a CalendarApp CalendarEvent object from IDs.
 * This version utilizes the Calendar API via UrlFetchApp, so
 * requires no enablement. However, it's more complex.
 *
 * @param {string} calendarId   ID of calendar to be searched
 * @param {string} eventId      Event ID to match
 *
 * @returns {CalendarEvent}     CalendarApp CalendarEvent object or null
 */
function getEventById(calendarId, eventId) {
  // Prepare a GET request to API URL, to Get event by ID.
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId"
            .replace("calendarId",calendarId)
            .replace("eventId",eventId);

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  }

  // Send request
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();
  var text = response.getContentText();

  // If result code is 200OK, process response text
  if (rc == 200) {
    // The event is contained in the response text; parse it into an object
    var event = JSON.parse(text);
    // This isn't a CalendarApp CalendarEvent though, so use the info
    // in the event to find it AGAIN as the right type.

    // Get start & end times of event. All-day events start at start.date,
    // while other events start at start.datetime. Likewise for end.
    var startTime = parseDate(event.start.date||event.start.dateTime);
    var endTime = parseDate(event.end.date||event.end.dateTime);

    // Get array of events that fall between startTime & endTime
    var calEvents = CalendarApp.getEvents(startTime, endTime);

    // Search through those events, looking for a match by ID
    for (var i=0; i<calEvents.length; i++) {
      var curId = calEvents[i].getId().split('@')[0];  // extract id from id@calendar.google.com
      var desc = calEvents[i].getDescription();
      if (curId == eventId) {
        // Mission accomplished; we have an Event object with given id!
        return calEvents[i];
      }
    }
    // We did not find matching event
    return null;
  }
  else
    // An error in fetch, anything BUT 200
    throw new Error( ""+rc+JSON.parse(text).message );
}
```

#### Helper function

Both versions of `getEventById()` require this helper function, provided in [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#listing_events).

```js
/**
 * From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#listing_events
 *
 * Parses an RFC 3339 date or datetime string and returns a corresponding Date
 * object. This function is provided as a workaround until Apps Script properly
 * supports RFC 3339 dates. For more information, see
 * https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3860
 * @param {string} string The RFC 3339 string to parse.
 * @return {Date} The parsed date.
 */
function parseDate(string) {
  var parts = string.split('T');
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/-/g, '/');
  return new Date(parts.join(' '));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this Mogsdad. I have been looking at the Advanced Calendar Service option, on the face of it the code looks more accessible to me. I will update my initial post with progress...

Comment: Hi Mogsdad, the helper function doesn't work anymore. Any idea why ? I wrote a new one myself but I still wonder why it suddenly stopped working.I used an example value like this : 2016-03-30T06:00:00.000Z , values with TZ indication work normally (but client javascript in a webapp returns the first model !)

Comment: Hi Serge. It works for me - I just grabbed the code from the docs, enabled the calendar API, and ran it. Not sure what you mean by the client js part.

Comment: As of Jul 2017 (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761294), the issue has been tagged as fix and the helper function `parseDate(...)` is no longer needed as you can now use `new Date(event.start.date || event.start.dateTime`.

Comment: For `getEventById(...)`, `var calEvents = CalendarApp.getEvents(startTime, endTime);` didn't work for me, but I have to pass my `calendar` instance and use it as `var calEvents = calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);`

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve your event from its ID you are (most probably) using the method [getEventSerieById(ID)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEventSeriesById(String)) which returns a [CalendarEventSeries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series), not a [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event).

If you take a look at these 3 referenced docs, you'll notice that CalendarEventSeries class has no `setTime()` method.

The error message you get is actually quite explicit in this case.

You should find a few posts that deal with this issue, this one for example : [Create Google Calendar Events from Spreadsheet but prevent duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788897/create-google-calendar-events-from-spreadsheet-but-prevent-duplicates/15790894#15790894)

Comment: Thanks for the info Serge. I'll give that read now. As far as I'm aware though, I'm not using anything related to series... when I initially create the event I store the ID using this: 

 dbsheet.getRange("P"+rowNumber).setValue(event.getId()); 

which generates something like this: '38be9v478l3ga8pjo58ht0i008@google.com

and when I want to edit it (in a separate function) I pull it back out for use like this:

var id = sh.getRange("P"+rowNumber).getValues();

I'm sure there's good reason for the error - but I'm failing to see it!

Comment: The reason for the error is described in the answer Serge linked to. Using an `eventID` to retrieve an event means that you must use `getEventSeriesById(iCalId)` - there is no other method that accepts an ID to grab an event. That method returns an `eventSeries` object - even for single events. The `eventSeries` object does not have a method `setTime()`. See [issue 1154](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1154).

Comment: Apologies, I was indeed using getEventSeriesById, I have no recollection of doing that at all... but there it is! var event = MDcalendar.getEventSeriesById(id);

So yes, exactly why setTime() isn't an available method like all the others I'll never understand, but thanks for clarifying the error for me.