# How to exclude all day events from Google calendar api searches?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a small script that pulls down my meetings via the [Google Calendar Events.list API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).  I'd like it to ignore my "all day" meetings.  It seems like it's not possible but I wanted to ask if anyone knows how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Event Resource Representation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource). (I've added comments.)

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#event",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  ...
  "start": {
    "date": date,               // All-day only
    "dateTime": datetime,       // Others only
    "timeZone": string
  },
  "end": {
    "date": date,               // All-day only
    "dateTime": datetime,       // Others only
    "timeZone": string
  },
  ...
}
```

The representation doesn't point out that all these properties are not present in every instance.

It turns out that all-day events start have a `start.date` property, while  other events start have a `start.datetime`. Likewise for `end`. You can simply use that to filter out the uninteresting events.

You'll see these properties used in [Google Apps Script: event.setTime error and time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652240/google-apps-script-event-settime-error-and-time-format/30657751#30657751).

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the "date" vs "dateTime" difference.  Is there a way to filter that at the server level?  I'd rather not have to get back all events and filter on the client end.

Comment: The query parameter `q` supports free-text queries, which is the only filter option other than start & end periods. I haven't found any way to get that to filter all-day events. If you were really disciplined, you could include identifying text in event titles or descriptions, then use `q` to seach those. But I think the most straight-forward approach is to pull the list for all, then remove undesirables from the result list.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out how to use `q` to do it either. Oh well.  I'll likely go with your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mogsdad I have events in calendar as abc 1, abc 2 but if i want to search for a specific event when I pass q=abc it displays all abc events but If i pass q=abc 1 it gives empty. Any suggestions please? I use calendar API mentioned https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list