# Apps Scripts .getStartTime() doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

so i have a script that gets information from google calendar.

```js
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
var events = cal.getEventSeriesById(eventId);
var details = [[events.getTitle(), events.getDescription(), events.getStartTime(), events.getEndTime()]];
```

but whenever i try to run it, i get the error 
`TypeError: Cannot find function getStartTime in object CalendarEventSeries.`
why doesn't it work?, .getStartTime is a function listed on google's own website
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getStartTime()

Comment: Please use the Stack snippet only for JavaScript/HTML/CSS runnable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getStartTime is defined on the CalendarEvent class and not CalendarEventSeries. That's why you are getting the error.
Please check the documentation -

CalendarEvent : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event
CalendarEventSeries : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series

Comment: omg, google and its different classes, makes things so confusing, getting the start time of a event when i know the event id shouldn't be impossible.....

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652240/google-apps-script-event-settime-error-and-time-format#answer-30657751