# How can I import the last row ONLY of a spreadsheet to my calendar using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have been able to create a script to import a spreadsheet (delivery schedule) to a calendar. It works great, but I am constantly adding new deliveries to the schedule. When I import it to the calendar, it imports everything every time. Is there a way to have ONLY the last row imported and not the whole spreadsheet?

This is the script that I am using...

```
var DELIVERY_IMPORTED = "DELIVERY_IMPORTED";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
var menuEntries = [{name: "Import Events in Calendar", functionName: "importCalendar"}];
ss.addMenu("Calendar", menuEntries);
}

function importCalendar() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 5;   // Number of rows to process
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var title = row[1]; // Name
var location = row[2]; 
var startDate = row[3]; // Start Date
var description = row[4]; 
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Calendar Name')[0];
var advancedArgs = {description: description, location: location};
cal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(startDate), advancedArgs);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if you have added TWO rows? You may want to look at [Create Google Calendar Events from Spreadsheet but prevent duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15790894/1677912).

Comment: to keep it as simple as your script is, I'd recommend to simply colorize the rows that are already exported to your calendar. Its simple (`setBackground('#red')` for example) and very "visual". Then process only the rows that are not colorized yet. I think only a couple of lines added to your code will do the job. If you want something more sophisticated and well written then Mogsdad reference (see above) will be the solution ;-)  note please remove this `SpreadsheetApp.flush();`  , it's useless here and use `getLastRow()` to get the number of rows to process

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions. I did however go with Mogsdad's suggestion and with a little tweaking it works fabulously. Thanks again for the help!! =D

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one new lime each time, you can use [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) to get the index of the last row with content.

Else you might use Properties service to store the last imported row, and start from there.