# How do I construct a link to a Google Calendar event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

If I [have the event ID of a Google Calendar event](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123396/207), for example:

> 4htgpmm1hmak744r0kbkdcodar@google.com

How can I construct a URL to view the event details in the Google Calendar interface?

For example, if I go to a google calendar event, I see a URL such as this:

> https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/NGh0Z3BtbTFobWFrNzQ0cjBrYmtkY29kYXIgZXVndTlrYW4xZGRpMXBtaTZzazNpYjWoNmdAZw

What function/algorithm can I run to go from `4htgpmm1hmak744r0kbkdcodar@google.com` to `NGh0Z3BtbTFobWFrNzQ0cjBrYmtkY29kYXIgZXVndTlrYW4xZGRpMXBtaTZzazNpYjWoNmdAZw`?

Bonus: A bonus would be if there was also a shortcut method that worked on a [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) via Google Apps Script. For example, if there was a method such as `getUrl()` just like there is a [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getId()) method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the same event can exist in multiple calendars (e.g. by inviting others to it), the event id is not sufficient information.

To construct a URL you need both the event id ([refresher for how find it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56741966/35690)), AND the Calendar ID (see below for instructions as to how to find it). [You'll then need to encode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46428456/35690) both as base64, and finally you'll you have a valid Google Calendar event link.

For the following instructions, imagine we have an event, Event1, and it exists in both calendars, CalendarA and CalendarB.

In the Google Calendar interface, you would be able to view any of these combinations:

- Event1 in CalendarA
- Event1 in CalendarB

Let's assign the following IDs:

- Event1 ID: 4htgpmm1hmak744r0kbkdcodar@google.com
- CalendarA ID: eugu9kan1ddi1pmi6sk3ib56g@group.calendar.google.com
- CalendarB ID: afd3zeuguoepmi32s5i56g@group.calendar.google.com

#### To construct an event URL:

1. Get the `event-id`, which is the event id without the `@google.com`

   E.g. for Event1 we have `4htgpmm1hmak744r0kbkdcodar`
2. Get the `calendar-id`, which is the calendar id with the `@group.calendar.google.com` replaced with `@g`

   E.g. for CalendarA we have `eugu9kan1ddi1pmi6sk3ib56g@g`
3. Join the two values with a space in the middle.

   ```
   <event-id> <calendar-id>
   ```

   E.g. for Event1 + CalendarA, we have:

   ```
   4htgpmm1hmak744r0kbkdcodar eugu9kan1ddi1pmi6sk3ib56g@g
   ```
4. Encode the value as base64 (e.g. on https://www.base64decode.org):

   ```
   NGh0Z3BtbTFobWFrNzQ0cjBrYmtkY29kYXIgZXVndTlrYW4xZGRpMXBtaTZzazNpYjWoNmdAZw==
   ```
5. Remove the training `==`:

   ```
   NGh0Z3BtbTFobWFrNzQ0cjBrYmtkY29kYXIgZXVndTlrYW4xZGRpMXBtaTZzazNpYjWoNmdAZw
   ```
6. You can now append this value to `https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=` (view event page) or `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/` (edit event page):

   ```
   https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NGh0Z3BtbTFobWFrNzQ0cjBrYmtkY29kYXIgZXVndTlrYW4xZGRpMXBtaTZzazNpYjWoNmdAZw

   or

   https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/NGh0Z3BtbTFobWFrNzQ0cjBrYmtkY29kYXIgZXVndTlrYW4xZGRpMXBtaTZzazNpYjWoNmdAZw
   ```
7. You're done! That URL will take you to the calendar event in the Google interface.

---

## How to find the calendar ID

If you need instructions for how to find the calendar id...

#### To find the calendar ID:

1. Go to the calendar settings
2. Scroll down until you find the calendar id field.

   This might be a value that ends with `@group.calendar.google.com`, your email address, or some other value.

If you are having trouble finding the calendar id, another tool that might help is [adding the `eventdeb=1` parameter to the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51704714/35690), going to the *Troubleshooting info* of an event, and then looking for either the `organizer` or `participant` values, both of which contain calendar ids.

---

## In Apps Script

```
var eventUrl = "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=" +
                  Utilities.base64Encode(event.getId().split('@')[0] +
                  " " + 
                  event.getOriginalCalendarId())
                  .replace(/\=/g, '');
```

Comment: This is probably the most interesting answer about calendar service I've ever read. Still wondering where you got all these information  Anyway, thanks a lot and again: congratulations!

Comment: excellent answer, I added a few comments in a solution further down (as it's too long for a regular comment)

Answer (score 1):

@Senseful had was a super helpful answer, and it works!

A few important things to note adding to the above. Firstly, when base64 encoding, you'll end up with a == at the end, remove that

Second, the base calendar URL will not work when the calendar the event belongs to does not belong in the primary account the user is logged in with. For example, if you're logged into 3 accounts, you'll have a different URL for each one e.g.

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/...

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/2/r/...

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/3/r/...

and so on... I don't think there's a solution that'll help with this situation since it's impossible to predict what accounts a specific user is logged into at any time.

Comment: Replacing the number 0,1,2 with the email address of the user (calendar) works. (https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/email@gmail.com/r/...)

Answer (score 0):

If your calendar ID is `4htgpmm1hmak744r0kbkdcodar@google.com`, then you can create link such as `https://calendar.google.com/u/0/r/eventedit?src=4htgpmm1hmak744r0kbkdcodar@google.com`