# Is is possible to construct a link to a google calendar event that works when multiple accounts are logged in?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928044/how-do-i-construct-a-link-to-a-google-calendar-event#new-answer?newreg=12d92042b04e46288758a6a3504b5796) works to construct a link to a google calendar event, however, it will not work if you are signed in to more than 1 google account in your browser.

When signed into more than one account, the URL adds parameters like this: .../calendar **/b/1/r/** eventedit/... which change depending on which account you're viewing.

Is there any way to construct a link that will work regardless of how many google accounts are logged in on the browser?