# Can't get calendar event ID to be linked in a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

good day!

I was able to create different calendar events using googlesheets thanks as well to our community. However, I now want to put a hyperlink of that created event in a column next to my calendar details. I've as well read about the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553846/get-link-url-to-an-calendar-event-in-google-apps-script), but can't seem to follow it. I'm pretty confused by what the answer meant as *"For given `event` object of type [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) and given `calendarId`"*.

In my code, I though the `event` was `inviteID = eventCal.getEventById(calendarId).split('@')` while the `calendarId` is `calendarId = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`. However, when I now encode them with base64, the eventID generated doesn't match the generated one in my calendar. I've tried out several iterations but still to no avail.

Please check out my code below (I've only included the lines which I think are relevant for easier reading):

```
    function sendInvites(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
      eventCal.createEvent(title, sDateTime, eDateTime, details);
      var inviteID = eventCal.getEventById(calendarId).split('@');
      var inviteURL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/" + Utilities.base64Encode(inviteID[0]+""+calendarId);
      sheet.getRange(startrow + x, 26).setValue('=HYPERLINK("' + inviteURL + '","View")');
      }
```

My suspicion is that I'm not correctly extracting the eventID or calendarId. I hope for your guidance on this.

Thanks!

Comment: The post that you mentioned was from 2015. Have you read [How do I construct a link to a Google Calendar event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53928045/1330560)

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, yes I've read this one. But from what I understood, I have to manually open the event in my calendar and get its ID, and as well manually get my calendar ID. Or was I wrong on this assumption?

Comment: How did you propose to find the eventid otherwise?

Comment: @J.Mapz I have posted an answer modifying your code so that it properly creates the URL... However, I am unsure as to whether the URL will work as an "invite" URL or not...

Comment: @Tedinoz, I believe I just lack the understanding of the concepts in programming. Pretty new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the event id from the `event` object returned by the `createEvent()` method call. I have corrected your code so that it actually gets the proper identifier to use with the eventedit URL:

```js
function sendInvites(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var event = calendar.createEvent(title, sDateTime, eDateTime, details);
  var inviteID = Utilities.base64Encode(event.getId().split("@")[0] + " " + calendarId);
  var inviteURL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/" + inviteID;
  sheet.getRange(startrow + x, 26).setValue('=HYPERLINK("' + inviteURL + '","View")');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! After a few modification following your route, it worked! :)

Comment: @J.Mapz Glad to hear!! If you think the modifications you made to my answer are relevant to your original question, please consider sharing them so anyone who finds this question can see the resolution. Thanks a lot

Comment: @J.Mapz Please share you mods if they are relevant. It may help others in the future.