# How to publish an event using the Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm able to create an event using [insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), but I would like to get the link I can give to my users so this screen appears:

[image]

The link looks like this: `https://calendar.google.com/event?action=TEMPLATE&tmeid=Mm4zaXFnZHEyZHRwMG1qOTRtdW1idW5wanMgbFjaG9jYWJAbQ&tmsrc=myemail@gmail.com`

In the GUI this is called "Publish Event"

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I do this using the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

I think that the link might not be able to be directly retrieved by the Calendar API. But, I think that the structure of link can be created using the calendar ID and `htmlLink` of the event retrieved by the methods of "Events: get" and "Events: list" in Calendar API. In this answer, I would like to propose the method for this. The flow of this method is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve the calendar ID.

   - In your case, it's `tmsrc=myemail@gmail.com`.
2. Retrieve the event ID.

   - In this case, you can retrieve this using the methods of "Events: list" in Calendar API like below.

     ```
       curl \
         'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events?timeMax=###&timeMin=###' \
         --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
         --header 'Accept: application/json' \
         --compressed
     ```
3. Retrieve `htmlLink` using the method of "Events: get" in Calendar API. Please use the retrieved event ID here.

   ```
    curl \
      'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId}' \
      --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
      --header 'Accept: application/json' \
      --compressed
   ```

   - `htmlLink` is like `https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=###`. `###` is the base65 encoded event ID and calendar ID. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46428456) So also, you can create this. This is used for the next section.
4. Create the link you want.

   - The link is like `https://calendar.google.com/event?action=TEMPLATE&tmeid=###&tmsrc={calendarId}`
   - `###` of the value of `eid` can be retrieved from the retrieved `htmlLink`.

#### References:

I think that as a test, you can retrieve the values using "Try this API" of the following pages.

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)
- [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)