# How to maintain date format in export to CSV in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export a Google Spreadsheet to CSV using the below function in Google Apps Script. Is it possible to maintain the date formatting in the CSV?

If I use the menu option instead to download as CSV, the date formatting is maintained.

I'm using the following function to export to CSV:

```
function exportToCSV(file) {

  // Get the selected range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheets()[0];
  var range = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),ws.getLastColumn())

  try {
    var data = range.getValues();

    var csvFile = undefined;

    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;

    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }

  return csvFile;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
        data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
      }
    }
```

to this (one line added):

```
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      data[row][col] = isDate(data[row][col]);      // Format, if date
      if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
        data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
      }
    }
```

You need to add these utilities, which I've copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14995676/1677912). The `isDate()` function originated with Martin Hawksey's [Google Apps event manager](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AqGkLMU9sHmLdFRSUjEyT0lDbk1TeU02eF9jRnpCNFE), and the `isValidDate()` function was found in another SO answer, as noted in the comments.

The date format in `isDate()` can be changed to suit your needs. Refer to [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate%28Date,String,String%29) for more info.

```
// From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684
// Returns 'true' if variable d is a date object.
function isValidDate(d) {
  if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]" )
    return false;
  return !isNaN(d.getTime());
}

// Test if value is a date and if so format
// otherwise, reflect input variable back as-is. 
function isDate(sDate) {
  if (isValidDate(sDate)) {
    sDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sDate), TZ, "dd MMM yy HH:mm");
  }
  return sDate;
}
```