# Download CSV with formatted date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, formatdatetime

In Google Sheets Script I have the following array

```
  data.forEach(function(row){
    if(row[0]==""){
      results.push([row[1],row[4].toString(Utilities.formatDate(row[4],"GMT-5","yyyy-MM-dd")));
      row[0] = "Exported";
    }           
  });
  //Use SetValues to set results[] to sheet
  //Download file as CSV
```

The problem I'm having is that the date still shows in Long format in the CSV file instead of the format I have set. The sheet shows it in the correct format.

Thanks for your help.

[Google Sheets result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwCC6.png)

[CSV result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLEVq.png)

Comment: Well, what does the `toString` method do on whatever `row[4]` returns? Because you're passing the result of `formatDate` to that function. Also, if `Utilities.formatDate` is something built into Google Sheets' API, I'd add the tag for that to your question; otherwise people will ask about it.

Comment: thanks added the tag

Comment: I used `tostring` to try to make it push as a text element instead of date.  Didn't work.  I also tried `Utilities.formatDate(row[4],"GMT-5","yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: This post answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804014/how-to-maintain-date-format-in-export-to-csv-in-google-apps-script