# try catch does not catch invalid date

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to validate a date input, so if it is correct, I handle one way, and if invalid, I handle another...

```
var date, datestring, e;

datestring = "2012-03-222";

try {
  date = new Date(datestring);
  /* Ends up logging `Invalid Date`
  */

  console.log(date);
} catch (_error) {
  e = _error;
  /* Should come here and log `Error: Invalid Date` or the likes
  */

  console.log("Erorr: " + e);
}
```

I could just check the returned string, and see if it is `Invalid Date` or not, but am both surprised that `try/catch` does not work for this scenario, and concerned that there might be other error messages I do not match.

How should I handle this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Date objects do not throw an error if they are invalid. There is a method described [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript) that will determine if a date is valid.