# Logic in if/else (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Have a small if/else problem in javascript. i don't see the logic...

The function should check if two dates are present and give alerts if it's not present. If everything is OK, it should say so...

```
function update_booking() {
    //from_date = The date of arrival
    //to_date = The date of departure

    var alert = ""; //reset alerts

    //get variables from booking form input
    var from_date = new Date(document.getElementById('from').value);
    var to_date = new Date(document.getElementById('to').value);

    //if arrival and departure date is present
    if(from_date && to_date) {
        var alert = "Everything is OK";
    }

    //if one or two dates are missing
    else {
        //if arrival and departure dates are missing
        if(from_date == 'undefined' || to_date == 'undefined'){
            var alert = "Arrival date and departure date are missing";  
        }

        //if from_date is missing update with value from to_date
        if(from_date == 'undefined') {
            var alert = "Arrival date are missing";
        }

        //if to_date is missing update with value from from_date
        if(from_date == 'undefined') {
            var alert = "Departure date are missing";
        }
    } //end else if one or more date(s) missing

    //write alerts
    document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = alert;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to tell us what you expect to happen and what really happens.

Comment: By the way, don't define `var alert` anywhere except the top of the function. See [this about var hoisting in Javascript](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

Comment: Are you confused between `"undefined"` and `undefined`?

Comment: For one, it should be `== undefined` (without quotes), but I don't think `new Date()` returns undefined if the constructor is not a valid date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value of Date is invalid, `new Date(datestring)` returns an object that is Not a Number (NaN).

For example, both `new Date("")` and `new Date(" ")` return an object that is NaN, while `new Date("04-29-2013")` does not.

So, I would recommend changing the search for `undefined` to NaN using `isNaN()` as in:

```
if(isNaN(from_date) || isNaN(to_date)){
```

Comment: Good approach. However, `new Date(garbage)` doesn't actually return `NaN`. It does return an object such that `isNaN()` returns `true`, but `typeof(new Date("xyz"))` is `'object'`, while `typeof(NaN)` is `'number'`.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Thanks, good catch. I edited the response to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

`new Date` will not return `undefined`

```
> new Date("")
Invalid Date
```

So looking at your code

```
if(from_date == 'undefined' || to_date == 'undefined'){
```

It will never go into that if statement.

To check if a date is valid, you want to [use isNaN with getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353711/14104)

Comment: Last date *I* had did.

Comment: @DaveNewton - It depends on the execution environment. In node.js, it behaves as in this answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton oh buddy oh pal, are you dreaming of your Java stuff?

Comment: @ epascarello @TedHopp Oh, I was talking about girls; what were YOU guys talking about?!

Comment: @DaveNewton it is too early to be hitting the bottle.

Comment: @epascarello I don't get it, it's a day ending in Y.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Ah, girls. Well, it still depends on the environment. :)

Comment: @TedHopp (Insert Dexter-ish "execution environment" quip here.)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function update_booking() {
//from_date = The date of arrival
//to_date = The date of departure
//get variables from booking form input
var from_date = document.getElementById('from').value;
var to_date =document.getElementById('to').value;

//if arrival and departure date is present
if(from_date && to_date) {
    alert( "Everything is OK");
}

//if one or two dates are missing
else {
    //if arrival and departure dates are missing
    if(from_date == ""|| to_date == ""){
        alert("Arrival date or departure date are missing");  
    }

    //if from_date is missing update with value from to_date
    if(from_date == "") {
        alert("Arrival date are missing");
    }

    //if to_date is missing update with value from from_date
    if(to_date == "") {
        alert("Departure date are missing");
    }
} //end else if one or more date(s) missing
```

}

Comment: that is very easy with jquery

Comment: This doesn't guard against badly formatted dates, typos, etc. (e.g., all spaces, or weird things like "Janary 3/2013").