# jquery validate using multiple variable

Tags: jquery, validation

I have 3 variable in my html:

1. Start Date (text input)

   ```
   <input size="16" name="start_date" type="text"  class="m-wrap">
   ```
2. End Date (text input)

   ```
   <input size="16" name="end_date" type="text"  class="m-wrap">
   ```
3. Frequency (dropdown)

   ```
   <select class="span3 chosen" name="summarize" tabindex="1">
      <option value="1">15 minutes</option>
      <option value="2">30 minutes</option>
      <option value="3">1 hour</option>
      <option value="4">3 hours</option>
   </select>
   ```

I would like to have validation input between 3 variable using jquery that, if diff(start_date and end_date) > 3 month, summarize can be used only value >= 1 hour (value 3 and 4). All this variable in id=Form_1.

How can i make this validation ? Any sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest using this plugin with a custom validation rule.
http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Your last part is very unclear. and @CharliePrynn I dont think the  this plugin can do that specific task..

Comment: The plugin accepts custom methods (Rules). The function would just return true/false depending on the outcome of the date comparison.

Comment: @RoyiNamir during form submit, i want to check input of start_date, end_date and summarize, if difference between start_date and end_date >= 3 month, then value of summarize should be >= 1 hour

Comment: @CharliePrynn this plugin wont write things for him , he still need to write JS.he's asking about the core js logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using jQuery validation plugin. If not, the logic can still be used. I admit it's very crude. Add the following method to `additional-methods.js`. This file comes along with `jquery.validate.js`.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("frequency", function(value, element) {
  var startdate = Date.parse($('input[name="start_date"]').val();
  var enddate = Date.parse($('input[name="end_date"]').val();
  difference = enddate-startdate;
  if(difference>7776000){
    if(value>2)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  else
    return true;
}, "Enter a higher frequency");
```

Now add the class `frequency` to your frequency select box.
Don't forget to include `additional-methods.js` file in your html. This adds a new custom rule for validation. Feel free to tinker.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

    $('input[name="start_date"], input[name="end_date"]')
    .change(function () {

        // check that both dates are populated and valid, if not than return

        // if the difference between the start date and the end date is more than
        // three months, than hide options less than an hour, otherwise return
        $('select[name="summarize"] > option:lt(2)').hide();

    });

});
```

[Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

[Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery UI Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). Here you can easily define custom rules validation and then assign to a input field. Let me know if you face any issue.