# split string doesn't work

Tags: javascript

for my form validation i wrote a function that split the date in 3 pieces.
The pieces are split by "\"

So the date looks like "01\01\2013"

here's my function

```
function check_date() {

                    var input = $('#start_date').val();
                    var lines = input.split('\\');
                    if (lines[0] <= 31) {
                        $('#start_date').css({'border': '1px solid #b0b0b0'});
                    } else {
                        $('#start_date').css({'border': '1px solid red'});
                    } 
                    if (lines[1] <= 12) {
                        $('#start_date').css({'border': '1px solid #b0b0b0'});
                    } else {
                        $('#start_date').css({'border': '1px solid red'});
                    }

                }
```

but this doesn't work at all...

is there anyone who can help?

Thx :)

Comment: The date is split by `/`.... not \`\\`\

Comment: sorry, misstyped the date :) i edited the question

Comment: Retagged as `javascript`. This isn't a `jquery` question.

Comment: Can you use the console to see if `input` really is what you think it is? Because if it's what you say it is, there is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Your code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/mruv6/

Comment: okay, this is stupid, i forgot to call the function in the onblur of the input ... =) thx all..

Comment: @BrechtSchepens: I recommend using a `Date` object to check for valid/invalid dates (then you can use something [similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript) to see if it's good). Checking if <= 31 days is only good if it's not, say, February.

Comment: okay, i'm going to take a look at it :) thx

Answer (score 1):

You're splitting by `\\` but the date is split by `/`.

Do you mean `input.split('/');`?

`\\` is equal to a literal backslash character, which would work fine if the date was `01\01\2013`.

You say that it was actually `\\` but it works fine?

```
var input = '01\\01\\2013';
var lines = input.split('\\');

if (lines[0] <= 31) {
    console.log('Lines[0] is OK'); //It reaches this
} else {
    console.log('Lines[0] is NOT OK');
}

if (lines[1] <= 12) {
    console.log('Lines[1] is OK'); //It reaches this
} else {
    console.log('Lines[1] is NOT OK');
}
```