# How to prevent JavaScript Date Constructor from accepting invalid dates?

Tags: javascript, date

I realize that this probably a feature, but I need the Date Constructor to bail on an invalid date not automagically roll it to the appropriate date.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
new Date('02/31/2015');
```

becomes

```
Tue Mar 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Sorry if this has already been asked, I wasn't able to/am too stupid to find it :).

Comment: Parse date strings yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  It has validation and overflow calculations among other Date object enhancements.  Thanks to Kevin Williams for

Comment: For those reading this answer sever years later, note that the moment.js library is no longer being supported and people should find other libraries for managing dates/times.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you cannot force a failure on illegal dates. The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) claim, the observed behaviour should only happen when the constructor is called with more than 1 argument, but this condition does not appear to hold (at least it doesn't on chrome 40).

However, you can re-convert the Date and compare it with the original string:

```
var s = '02/31/2015';
var d = new Date(s)
var s_re = d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' } );
if (s === s_re) {
    // ok
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can count on the string input being formatted as digits (no weekday or month names), you can look at the input before creating a Date object.

```
function validDate(s){
    //check for day-month order:
    var ddmm= new Date('12/6/2009').getMonth()=== 5;

    //arrange month,day, and year digits:

    var A= s.split(/\D+/).slice(0, 3), 
    month= ddmm? A[1]: A[0], 
    day= ddmm? A[0]: A[1], 
    y= A.pop(), 

    //figure february for given year:

    feb= y%4== 0 && (y%100 || y%400== 0)? 29: 28, 

    // set maximum days per month:

    mdays= [0, 31, feb, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

    //if the string is a valid calendar date, return a date object.
    //else return NaN (or throw an Error):

    return mdays[parseInt(month, 10)]-A[1]>= 0? new Date(s): NaN;
}
```

**validDate('02/29/2015')**

/*  returned value: (Number)
NaN
*/

Answer (score -2):

You can't set a JavaScript Date object to an invalid date.

Nevertheless you may want to [check if a date is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1353684/3774551).

Comment: `mydate.setTime(NaN)`

Comment: Isn't Feb 31 invalid?  Because I can send it to the date constructor.  Not that I don't believe you, I just don't understand.