# Jquery, datepicker on manual entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a datepicker and I noticed that if I enter manually a date, which means entering a value of the form mm/dd/yyyy without using the calendar, the date is not updated.

I would like to allow the possibility to change manually the date. Thus, I need to **validate** and **update** the date entered.

I started by trying to use the function `change` like this:

```
$('myDatepickerId').change(...)
```

It was not working so after some research I found the `onClose:` attribute.

Which I use like this:

```
onClose: function(date) {
           this_.tripWidget.inputChanged({
                date : date,
            });
        }
```

This updates the date, but I'm not sure how to validate it.

I'm looking for a function associated with datepicker to ensure that the date entered is of the correct format. Is there anyway to verify that the date is in the datepicker calendar?

**Edit:**

I found a related question here: 
[Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Then I tried (unsuccessfully) to adapt the answer to my problem:

```
onClose: function(date) {
            this_.tripWidget.inputChanged({
                if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === "[object Date]" && !isNaN(date.getTime()){
                    alert("Please enter a valid date.");
                }
                date : date,
            });
        }
```

Comment: I found a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript However I'm not able to adapt the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is how I solved my problem:

```
var comp = date.split('/');
var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
var y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);
var date2 = new Date(y,m-1,d);
if(!(date2.getFullYear() == y && date2.getMonth() + 1 == m && date2.getDate() == d)) {
                alert('Please enter a valid date.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be something you want to validate in a server script when you send the request instead of in a javascript.

Comment: Of course data should always be validated server-side. But considering usability improvement, client-side validation is also recommend. by the way your "answer" should be a comment....

Answer (score 0):

You're likely going to have to do the validation independently of the DatePicker control. You can do something like this to A) Make sure it's a valid date and B) ensure it's in the desired format of mm/dd/yyyy

```
$('#myDatepickerId').on('input', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (isValidFormat(value) && isValidDate(value)) {
        $(this).addClass('valid');
    }
});

function isValidFormat(value) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^([01][0-12]\/[0-3][0-9]\/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9])$");
    return regex.test(value);
}
function isValidDate(value) {
    var date = new Date(value);
    return date != 'Invalid Date';
}
```

Here's a [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q2HYOmOeuGylNhqInuui)