# Not throwing exception while passing wrong date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to check if a date(in MM/dd/yyyy format) is a valid date in javascript. But while passing a wrong date, it is not able to distinguish.
I was using the below logic to check if it is a valid date or not.

```
var dt = document.forms["registerForm"]["dateOfBirth"].value;
    try{
        var d = new Date(dt);
        alert(d);
    }catch(err){
        alert("not a valid date");
        return false;
    }
```

while the dateOfBirth is "02/47/2016" it is not going to the exception block, rather it is interpreting "02/47/2016" as Fri Mar 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST). But when i tried with "02/03/2016" it is interpreting correctly as Wed Feb 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` constructor gets the day value and just adds that number of days, minus 1, to the first of the month, which explains the resulting date you get.

Using a library like `momentjs` makes life much easier when it comes to dealing with dates, but if you want to do this without additional library, then you could use the function below. If the `Date` constructor returns a date object, this function will format that date back to a string, comparing it with the original input. If they don't match, the function will return `undefined`, just like when an exception occurs. If they match, the date object is returned:

```js
function getDate(d) {
    function formatDate(d) {
        return [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()]
               .map( n => (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n ).join('/');
    }
    try {
        var d = new Date(dt);
        if (formatDate(d) != dt) return; // invalid
        return d;
    } 
    catch(err){}
}

var dt = '02/47/2016';
console.log(dt, getDate(dt) !== undefined);
var dt = '02/03/2016';
console.log(dt, getDate(dt) !== undefined);
```

Answer (score 1):

Enforce some structure when users enter the date in the form, e.g. MM/DD/YYYY.  If you don't you may end up with a date such as 02/10/2016 which could validly be Feb 10th or Oct 2nd depending on the country.

Past that, unless you have to be lean, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for validation, e.g.

```
alert(moment("02/10/2016", 'MM/DD/YYYY',true).isValid()); //true
```

Comment: Yes use moment. You'll keep your sanity.