# How to test Date(Invalid Date) with jasmine

Tags: javascript, date, testing, jasmine

To simplify, lets see this function getting date and returning a date modified (start of day):

```
const getStartOfDay = date => {
    const newDate = new Date(date);
  newDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  return newDate;
}
```

Now I want to implement some tests with invalid values i.e: `getStartOfDay(new Date("HELLO"));` function returns `Date(Invalid Date)`.

I tried to test like:

```
expect(util.getStartOfDay("hello")).toBe(new Date("hello"));
```

But I get:

> Expected Date(Invalid Date) to equal Date(Invalid Date).

Same error with `toEquals()`...

Other dates I compare with `getTime()` but here I cant... So I get stucked...

**Any idea of how can I test it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because in JS `NaN != NaN` and invalid date has `NaN` time. So you can check that `util.getStartOfDay("hello").getTime()` is `NaN`

```
expect(isNaN(util.getStartOfDay("hello").getTime())).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

With some insight from [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript).

```
const isValidDate = date => {
  if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === "[object Date]" ) {
    // it is a date
    if ( isNaN( date.getTime() ) ) {  // date.valueOf() could also work
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

describe("Suite", function() {
  it("handles invalid Dates", function() {
    expect(isValidDate(getStartOfDay("hello")) ).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/backpackcoder/jj3061fk/1/