# Can not compare the given date with today date using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am facing one issue. I need to compare the given date with the today date using Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```
function getCurrentDate(){
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();

    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) 
    {
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 

    if(mm<10) 
    {
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
    today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
    return today;
}

var givendate=new Date('19-01-2018');
var todaydate=$scope.getCurrentDate();
if (givendate >= todaydate) {
    console.log('bool',true);
}else{
    console.log('bool',false);
}
```

Here I should get the result `true` but here I am getting the console message as `false`. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: While debugging, also `console.log` `givendate` and `todaydate`, see where the mismatches are

Comment: What are the values of `givendate` and `todaydate`?

Comment: @CharlieMartin : Ohh..Its giving `Invalid Date` for givendate and `17-01-2018` for todaydate.

Comment: Maybe that's why it's `false`. Do you still need help solving the issue?

Comment: Then how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works. Like the others said, you need to ensure that you are specifying the date in the proper format as expected by the Date constructor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="today"></p>
<p id="text"></p>

<script>
today = new Date();
jan19 = new Date('2018-01-19')
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jan19;
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = today;
if (today < jan19) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'true';
}
else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'false';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments `givendate` is `"Invalid Date"` - that's why you have false.

So, before parsing a date, check [how to detect invalid date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

`new Date`tries to parse following [ISO 8601 format](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). Quoting:

> The formats are as follows. Exactly the components shown here must be present, 
>   with exactly this punctuation. Note that the "T" appears
>   literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time
>   element, as specified in ISO 8601.
>
> ```
>    Year:
>       YYYY (eg 1997)
>    Year and month:
>       YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
>    Complete date:
>       YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
>    Complete date plus hours and minutes:
>       YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
>    Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
>       YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
>    Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
> second
>       YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
> where:
>
>      YYYY = four-digit year
>      MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
>      DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
>      hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
>      mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
>      ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
>      s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
>      TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
> ```

Make sure you pass a correctly formatted date when constructing a date object. All the details you need on the subject can be found in JS MDN, on the [`Date.parse` topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue with your current date format(**`dd-MM-yyyy`**), then you may need to split the string by `-` and rearrange accordingly to make a valid date.

**JS Code**

```js
function getCurrentDate() {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10)
            dd = '0' + dd;
            if (mm < 10)
                mm = '0' + mm;
            today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
            return today;
        }

    var todayDate = getCurrentDate().toString();
    var givenDate = '19-01-2018';

    var todayDateArray = todayDate.split('-');
    var givenDateArray = givenDate.split('-');
    
    todayDate = new Date(todayDateArray[2] + '-' 
                       + todayDateArray[1] + '-' 
                       + todayDateArray[0]);
    
    givenDate = new Date(givenDateArray[2] + '-' 
                       + givenDateArray[1] + '-' 
                       + givenDateArray[0]);
    
    if(givenDate >= todayDate)
        console.log('bool', true);
    else
        console.log('bool', false);
```

Comment: I must admit, that looks quite ugly. Also, you're splitting the same string 3 times, instead of splitting it once and use the resulting array 3 times.

Comment: @Adelin : It's possible to split the string and store in a single array variable

Comment: Of course it's possible - but your code doesn't reflect that

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. If you don't want a custom formatted date then you can use this.

```js
function getCurrentDate(){
    var today = new Date();
    return today;
}

var givendate=new Date("2018-01-19");
var todaydate= getCurrentDate();
console.log(givendate);
console.log(todaydate);
if (givendate >= todaydate) {
    console.log('bool',true);
}else{
    console.log('bool',false);
}
```