# How can i validate <input type = "date"> and <textarea></textarea> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

When i try to validate Institute name and date of birth in my html form using javascript it is not working, i searched alot in google but i am not able to reach to the solution of my queries. Any type of help is appreciated.

```js
function validation() {
  var first_name = document.getElementById('Fname').value;
  var last_name = document.getElementById('Lname').value;

  var Institute_name = document.myForm.institute.value;
  var DOB = document.getElementById('dob').value;

  if (first_name == "") {
    document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML = "** Please fill this field";
    return false;
  }

  if ((last_name == "") && (first_name != "")) {
    document.getElementById('lname').innerHTML = "** Please fill this field";
    document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML = "";
    return false;
  }

  if ((Institute_name == '') && (last_name != "")) {
    document.getElementById('InstituteE').innerHTML = "** Please fill this field";
    document.getElementById('branchE').innerHTML = "";
    return false;
  }

  if (!DOB.value) {
    document.getElementById('DateOfBirth').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid birthday";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="wall">
      <form action="" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validation()" method="POST" class="bg-light">

        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 52px; color: bisque"><u>INTERNSHIP FORM</u></h1><br><br>
        <p>FIRST &nbsp;NAME :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="Fname" placeholder="First Name......" autocomplete="off">
          <span id="fname" class="text-danger"></span> LAST &nbsp;NAME :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="Lname" placeholder="Last Name........" autocomplete="off">
          <span id="lname" class="text-danger"></span>
        </p>

        <p>
          NAME &nbsp;OF &nbsp;THE &nbsp;INSTITUTE :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <br><br>
          <textarea name="institute" rows="3" cols="30" placeholder="Institute name...">
                            </textarea>
          <span id="InstituteE" class="text-danger"></span> DATE OF BIRTH :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" id="dob" autocomplete="off">
          <span id="DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span> </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-success" style="padding: 20px; font-size: 28px;"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <input type="reset" name="reset" value="RESET" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 20px; font-size: 28px;">
        </p>

      </form>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</code>
```

Here I am using span tag to print the error of not filling  that field, and made this tag's class = "danger".

Comment: Please explain "not working".

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 issues when I tried it with your code.

Textarea: - your textarea already contains spaces after loading - so when you check if it's empty, it will find content and therefore it's "filled"

```
(Institute_name == '')
```

So I would recommend to remove leading and trailing white spaces first, so only the "real content" will be checked (the js method `trim` will do this for you)

```
( Institute_name.trim() == '')
```

Date:
When you access the date field

```
var DOB = document.getElementById('dob').value;
```

you already get the value (e.g. 2018-09-22). So accessing the value twice

```
if(!DOB.value)
```

will always evaluate to `undefined` / false. So just check the variable again for e.g. empty string

```
if(DOB == '')
```

Beside that you can always check if it's a valid date input (see [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript))

Btw. I would recommend to look into Developer/Dev Tools of yor preferred browser - It really helps you to debug js code, inspect variables, etc. :-)

Comment: The  assertion that `if(!DOB.value)` will always evaluate to false is incorrect. Getting the value from the input doesn't affect the input's value. Since it's a primitive, the value is copied to *DOB* and the value of the input is unchanged.

Comment: That's right - the input is unchanged - but in Don's code `DOB` is already the value (string) of the input - `DOB.value()` is then `undefined` in that case

Comment: Ok, the way you put it wasn’t clear. `!DOB.value` is always true.

Comment: would any one of you provide me your email id, so that i can send you my html file with more validation.

Comment: No sorry, if you tried it and it still don't work, post your current code an we will help you

Comment: its 2465 line code and stack overlow not allowing me to post that big code.