# Angular with d3: Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,25.384615384…"

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am using d3 in an Angular 5 app to graph a line, and I can't seem to get my numbers right. I'm getting this error:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,25.384615384…".
```

I assume it's either something to do with how I'm parsing my dates, or date type, or the domain on my axis?

The d3 code in question looks like:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width - 100])
  .domain(<[Date, Date]>d3.extent(this.temp_data, function (d) { return parse(d['date']); }));

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .scale(x)
  .ticks((width + 2) / (height + 2))
  .tickSize(-height)
  .tickPadding(10)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %d, %H:%M:%S"))

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function (d) { return x(parseTime(d['date'])); })
  .y(function (d) { return y(d['temperature']); });
```

My data looks like in UTC format:

```
[{"temperature": "11.0", "date": "2018-10-10 20:36:27 UTC" }.
 {"temperature": "11.2", "date": "2018-10-10 20:34:27 UTC" },
 {"temperature": "10.9", "date": "2018-10-10 20:32:27 UTC" },
 {"temperature": "11.3", "date": "2018-10-10 20:30:27 UTC" },
 {"temperature": "11.0", "date": "2018-10-10 20:28:27 UTC" }]
```

Where might that error be coming from? 
Thanks! Any help or thoughts are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I know this is slightly different code but I am having the same problem on this codepen [HERE](https://codepen.io/lahesty/pen/YOGPwd).

thanks so much! I've been starting at it too long now and am starting to go in circles

Comment: Sorry yes, that was just a copy/paste error!

Comment: In `.domain(<[Date, Date]>d3.extent(this.temp_data, function (d) { return parse(d['date'])`, what is `parse` doing?

Comment: @ialarmedalien I thought I would need it to make the dates readable by the axis, perhaps it's overkill?

Comment: I just want to make sure that the x axis is setting up a valid domain—if it isn't, it could be what's causing the NaN values. To confirm, the NaN is from the `path` element that makes up the line - correct?

Comment: @ialarmedalien I can only assume so. Either that or an incorrect x axis. Because the graph will appear complete, except for the line and the labels on the x axis.

Comment: Can you create a minimal, complete working example for myself and others to take a look at? Also -- try using `parseTime` when you're setting the domain of the x axis to ensure it isn't that the x axis domain is invalid.

Comment: codepen created! It's in the post edit. It's the same problem just slightly different code. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your time parser is not working correctly -- if you log `temp_data`, you'll see the dates are all invalid.

Comment: Ah I see, am I not using proper formatting for UTC? I can't find the right alternative

Comment: the first one also needs to be `timeParse`, not `timeFormat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `timeParse` assigned to the variable `parseTimeUtc` is the correct one considering the format of the dates in your data.
2. Once you parse the dates in the `forEach` loop, you don't need to parse them again while setting the xAxis or within the `line` generator function.

   ```
   temp_data.forEach(function (d) {
     d.date = parseTime_utc(d.date)
     d.temperature = +d.temperature;
   });
   ```
3. All the dates are the same and so I've made slight changes (months) to make the line visible.
4. Added the following `style` to the line: `fill:none; stroke: steelblue;` to make the line visible.
5. You had a SVG appended within a SVG (copy/paste error I suppose). Anyway, changed `#watertemp_graph` to a `<div></div>`.

**Snippet:**

```js
var temp_data = [
{"temperature": "11.0", "date": "2018-08-22T14:53:37.267Z" },
 {"temperature": "11.2", "date": "2018-07-22T14:53:37.267Z" },
 {"temperature": "10.9", "date": "2018-08-22T14:53:37.267Z" },
 {"temperature": "11.3", "date": "2018-05-22T14:53:37.267Z" },
 {"temperature": "11.0", "date": "2018-08-22T14:53:37.267Z" }]

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %X"); //27-May-12 16:00:00. This is used for D3JS parsing
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %X");
 var parseTime_utc = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
var formatDate_utc = d3.timeFormat("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S");
// var parse = parseDate(moment.utc(d.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))

temp_data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.date = parseTime_utc(d.date)
        d.temperature = +d.temperature;
});

var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 70 },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Parse the date / time
    

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
      .ticks(5);

    // Define the line
    var valueline = d3.line()
      .x(function (d) { return x(d['date']); })
      .y(function (d) { return y(d['temperature']); });


    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("#" + "watertemp_graph")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(temp_data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(temp_data, function (d) { return d['temperature']; }));

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline(temp_data)).style('fill', 'none').style('stroke', 'steelblue');


    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="watertemp_graph">
 
  </div>
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmmbzw

Also, if you could let us know why you have the other `timeParse`rs and `timeFormat`s, maybe I can help you with using those as well.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** Need of a flexible parser?

> As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_parse) by Mike: **If a more flexible parser is desired, try multiple formats sequentially until one returns non-null** and my suggestion would be to be to further validate the non-null value (date) by following [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript#answer-1353711).

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps. My last question is what I might do differently if my dates are formatted like "2018-10-10 20:28:27 UTC" rather than what's on the codepen. Doing something like 'd3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")' will make them null. (that's why I have the other parsing/format variables, I'm not sure which I'd need for each date format)

Comment: Sure. Updated the post on how to get/write a flexible parser.

Comment: Great thank you so much! I didn't realize a guess-and-check type method was rather conventional :)

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it is. I use that a lot too to add flexibility.