# How to get Date object from ISO Date string without dash(-) and colon(:) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, icalendar

I was converting ICS to JSON, but it gave me date in the format like `"20190103T073640Z"`, How to I get date object from this string in Javascript?

I know there are lots of answers for *"how to convert ISO string to date object"*, but this string is missing dash and colon.

For e.g
When I add dash and colonn, it gives output correctly

`new Date("2019-01-03T07:36:40Z");`

But how to get a date object in javascript from date string like this without dash and colons `"20190103T073640Z"`??

**Edit for people who think this is duplicate -**
I have ICalendar file, I am using online converter to convert it to JSON, so the converter I am using giving out the date in that format which is not in the format which I can directly pass to `new Date()` to get a date object out of it. So is there any method which could parse "20190103T073640Z" string like this.

Thanks.

Comment: add dash and colon to the string. if you know this is always in same format.

Comment: Use proper date format, as the date string you are using is invalid. Refer this for checking if date is valid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about just extracting each date component, and creating a new Date object using the normal constructors?

```js
function parseIcsDate(icsDate) {
  if (!/^[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z$/.test(icsDate))
    throw new Error("ICS Date is wrongly formatted: " + icsDate);
  
  var year   = icsDate.substr(0, 4);
  var month  = icsDate.substr(4, 2);
  var day    = icsDate.substr(6, 2);
  
  var hour   = icsDate.substr(9, 2);
  var minute = icsDate.substr(11, 2);
  var second = icsDate.substr(13, 2);
  
  return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second));
}

var date = parseIcsDate("20190103T073640Z");
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the use of a library is justified (in case of other date operations), Luxon is an excellent choice:
https://moment.github.io/luxon/

```js
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

// Creates a DateTime instance from an ISO 8601-compliant string
const date = DateTime.fromISO('2019-01-03T07:36:40Z');

// Format date to ISO 8601 string
// -> '2019-01-03T08:36:40.000+01:00'
date.toISO();

// Set format to 'basic'
// -> '20190103T083640.000+0100'
date.toISO({format: 'basic'});

// We don't need milliseconds
// -> '20190103T083640+0100'
date.toISO({format: 'basic', suppressMilliseconds: true});

// My system uses a time zone with an offset of +01:00, which is used by Luxon as default.
// So I have to convert the date to UTC (offset +00:00).
// -> '20190103T073640Z'
date.toUTC(0).toISO({format: 'basic', suppressMilliseconds: true});

// As an one-liner
DateTime
    .fromISO('2019-01-03T07:36:40Z')
    .toUTC(0)
    .toISO({ format: 'basic', suppressMilliseconds: true })
```

Comment: None of these examples show how to *parse* the date from the format given in the OP to a `Date` object, which is what the question is.