# Validate ISOString format?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to validate if a field is a ISOString format?

It work when I use valid date such as `const create = '2018-08-02T02:07:49.214Z'` but it break the script when I use `const create = 'b';`

Example:

```js
//const create = '2018-08-02T02:07:49.214Z';
const create = 'b';


const dateParsed = new Date(Date.parse(create))
if(dateParsed.toISOString() === create){
 console.log(dateParsed.getTime())
} else {
 console.log('invalid date')
}
```

I get an error `RangeError: Invalid time value` but expecting `invalid date` from console log.

Comment: You can always just use `try-catch`

Comment: @TylerRoper No, `new Date(Date.parse("b"))` is an `Invalid Date` (a _truthy_ object), not `null`. It can be checked with `isNaN(Number(new Date(Date.parse("b"))))`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Huh. If you click the *"Copy snippet to answer"* button underneath OP's code and add `console.log(dateParsed)`, [it logs `null`](https://i.imgur.com/sXyAY7E.png). I suppose that explains my confusion. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, add below condition

```
!isNaN(dateParsed) && dateParsed.toISOString() === create
```

**Issue:**

console error is valid , as it throws error with toISOString() of invalid date

working code for reference

```js
const create = 'b';
const dateParsed = new Date(Date.parse(create))

if(!isNaN(dateParsed) && dateParsed.toISOString() === create){
 console.log(dateParsed.getTime())
} else {
 console.log('invalid date')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date(Date.parse(create))` will return an Invalid Date, since `Date.parse('b')` returns `NaN`. I would point you towards this question: [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript), which provides a couple ways to checking if a date is valid or not.

At least in this example case, it doesn't seem like ISO format is strictly required, but you should be able to construct a regex to at least match the structure (there may be other requirements for a truly valid ISO datestring, I'm not sure off the top of my head).