# Cannot find method createEvent(string,string,string)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a spreadsheet with +250 lines of prospects.
For each prospect I have a row in wish I inform the date we are supposed to meet.

I have tried to create a script so that the dates I input on the cell are automatically transformed into Google Calendar Events.

Still, each time I run the script I get the "Cannot find method (string, string, string)" error message.

I don't know if the fact that I have several blank cells is the problem.

There goes the code I tried to run:

```
function scheduleshifts() {
var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var CalendarId = Spreadsheet.getRange("Y2").getValue();
var eventcal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalendarId);

var signups = Spreadsheet.getRange("C3:V250").getValues();

for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++){
var shift = signups [x];
var startTime = shift[18];
var endTime = shift[19];
var title = shift[0];
eventcal.createEvent(title, new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime));
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the OP's question:

> I don't know if the fact that I have several blank cells is the problem.

Yes that is the problem because `getValues` returns an empty string as the value of a blank cell.

The solution is to include a condition to use a default date or to skip the row with empty cells for the `starTime` and `endTime` variables.

---

How about this alternative? Lets assume that the source data for `startTime` and `endTime` are Google Sheets date values or blanks (empty cells). If `startTime` or `endTime` are valid dates, then the calendar event is created, otherwise isn't.

```
function scheduleshifts() {
  var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var CalendarId = Spreadsheet.getRange("Y2").getValue();
  var eventcal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalendarId);

  var signups = Spreadsheet.getRange("C3:V250").getValues();

  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++){
    var shift = signups [x];
    var startTime = shift[18];
    var endTime = shift[19];
    var title = shift[0];
    if(isValidDate(startTime) && isValidDate(endTime)){
      eventcal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
      // Added the following line to prevent to exceed the limit of events created 
      // "in a short time"
      Utilities.sleep(1000); 
    }
  }
}
/* 
 * From the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353711/1595451 to 
 * "Detecting an “invalid date” Date instance in JavaScript"
 */
function isValidDate(d) {
  return d instanceof Date && !isNaN(d);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how do I do that? :/

Comment: @Marco I added an example.

Comment: @Rubén Could you please modify from `isValiadDate(startTime)` to `isValidDate(startTime)`? It's a typo.

Comment: @Tanaike Done! Thank you.

Comment: Dear All, it's working!
Thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function scheduleshifts() {
  var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var CalendarId = Spreadsheet.getRange("Y2").getValue();
  var eventcal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalendarId);

  var signups = Spreadsheet.getRange("C3:V250").getValues();

  for (x=0;x<signups.length;x++){
    var shift=signups[x];
    var startTime=shift[18];
    var endTime=shift[19];
    var title=shift[0];
    eventcal.createEvent(title, new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime));
    Utilities.sleep(18000);//9000 if G-Suite
  }
}
```

You just need to make sure that startTime and endTime strings are in a form that Date() constructor will accept. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Thanks everybody.
Unfortunately now I get a message saying I tried to create too many calendar events in too short amount of time. Please Try Again Later :/
There's also a suggestion to use "Utilities.sleep(1000)".
Is that actually relevant? How can it help?

Comment: function scheduleshifts() {
var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var CalendarId = Spreadsheet.getRange("Y2").getValue();
var eventcal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CalendarId);
  
var signups = Spreadsheet.getRange("C3:V250").getValues();

for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++){
var shift = signups [x];
var startTime = shift[18];
var endTime = shift[19];
var title = shift[0];
eventcal.createEvent(title, new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime));
}
}

Comment: Please post it in your question

Comment: If you have a regular Gmail account you can create an event every 18 seconds. 86400/5000.  Which means that a script will timeout after around 16 events. My understanding suggests that Google calculates a frequency limit in determining quotas rather that  counting for an entire day.  This isn't something I know for sure.  I just use this approach in avoiding quota limits in my own code and thus far it has served me well.