# Checking whether a Date is valid in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date, types

[These are the commonly accepted ways of doing it in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript).

However with Typescript is we do `!isNaN(someDate)`, typescript complains that we are using a method that accepts numbers, and not dates.

Thoughts on how to go about handling this?

Comment: Since you are specifically doing typechecking, what about `isNaN(somedate as any)`?

Comment: Got a point.  Javascript is a picky bastard :)

Comment: Just use `!isNaN(someDate.valueOf())`... or `getTime()` as [the accepted answer on the question you linked to shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353711/215552)...

Comment: Nice Both `as any` and `valueOf()` work!  Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

a Date object is not an number, but you can use `Date.getTime()`

getTime() return a number value or `NaN` if the Date is not valid