# Check if NaN without real variable

Tags: javascript

I have a [TIMER (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/8t014dub/), that takes a date and time and then counts the hours from the **starting date / time** the **current date / time**.

In my fiddle it just counts away from **January 01, 2020 14:00:00**, but on my website the user is able to change this date. – When he enters invalid information the timer outputs `NaN`.

When the users enters information, the timer is run again and the user get a new output. – When this happens, I would like to check, if the output is `NaN`, if so, I would like for another function to ben run, let's call it: `timerError()` – With this I will reset the timer and tell the user, that his input was invalid.

I know about `isNaN(variable)`, but I don't really have a variable here, so don't know how to check, if the timer output is `NaN`…

This is my JS:

```
                // TIMER Styling START
                function styleChars(targetEl) {
                    const val = targetEl.textContent;
                    const chars = val.split('');
                    targetEl.innerHTML = chars.map(c => `<span class="digit">${c}</span>`).join('');
                }
                
                const target = document.querySelector('.value_timer');
                console.log(target);
                styleChars(target);
                // TIMER Styling END
                
                // TIMER START
                var timerDate = "January 01, 2020 14:00:00";
                
                    function setTimer() {
                        // Month Day, Year Hour:Minute:Second, id-of-element-container.
                        countUpFromTime(timerDate, 'countup1');
                    };
                    
                    window.onload = setTimer();
                    
                    function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
                        let countDate = new Date(countFrom);
                        let now = new Date();
                        let timeDifference = (now.getTime() - countDate.getTime());

                        let value_timer = Math.floor(timeDifference / 1000 / 60 / 60);

                        let idEl = document.getElementById(id);
                        idEl.innerHTML = value_timer;
                        styleChars(idEl); // Pass element to styling function.

                        clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
                        countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function () {
                            countUpFromTime(countFrom, id);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
            
                // TIMER END
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't really have a variable here" ? Can't you use `isNaN(timeDifference)` ?

Comment: @Seblor Maybe I made a mistake, but I tried it: https://jsfiddle.net/aqto3kr6/ and unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: @SimonR. You should make the check and error handling before making all the calculus and printing the value, not at the bottom of everything.

Comment: The output basically is a span with the `id="countup1"` and then multiple spans inside that one, for each number, all with the `class="digit"`. – I have to admit, I'm still new to JS and I copied this code together and I do not fully understand every part of it.

Comment: @CristianSarghe When the user finishes typing in the new date, the function `setTimer()` is run. I tried putting the check at the start of that, but that didn't work… Maybe I'm also doing something wrong, could you maybe make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if `timerDate` is not a valid date string format, `new Date(timerDate)` will return an `InvalidDate`.

In your code, you need to check if `countDate` which is `new Date(timerDate)` is an Invalid Date. If so, handle the error accordingly.

You can [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript) by verifying `isNaN(countDate.getTime())`. It should be `true` if the Date is invalid.

EDIT: I have created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aojhrkb5/1/) that makes your code compliant with the changes.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer! – I tried this, but I think I'm doing something wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/bpc8wtxh/

Comment: @SimonR. I have edited my answer to include a Fiddle. Please check it

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. I see your fiddle is working and I want to edit this on: https://jsfiddle.net/bpc8wtxh/ so that the `test()` function, that's being run, when I click on the button, outputs one of two alerts, but I can't get it to work. – Your using `if (isNaN(countDate.getTime()))` to check if it is `NaN` but how? – I thought you would need something like: `if (isNaN(countDate.getTime()) === true)` – Why don't you have to compare it to something. / Again, still new to JS. 

Comment: @SimonR. Alright, you should understand how `setTimeout` works in the context of sync/async programming. You can also see that `countDate` does not exist outside the `countUpFromTime` function, which means you can not access it there, which is why JavaScript says it's `undefined` and does not have a `getTime()` child method. Check this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cq083v5o/ for a working version and a few code comments. Also, check Mozilla's documentation for Javascript Truthy values to understand why `=== true` is irrelevant there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: Thank you, so much!