# How to delete all rows of a Google sheet if their corresponding column1 value is NOT a valid date?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to delete all rows of a Google sheet if their corresponding column1 value is NOT a valid date. Not sure how to fix this issue. Please check the attached image where I want to delete each of the three rows as their corresponding column1 value is not a Valid Date.

Please note that there are other rows of data with valid date in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD` at a Google sheets.

[image: Date Issue]

Comment: A very quick and dirty way is to create a new column and put the formula `=isDate()`. Then write a script to delete the rows for which the cells of this column are False. You can do the full process in a Google script. But the first one is easier I think.

Comment: @Marios Not possible here to create a new column as there are triggers and other things associated. Google script is better, but how?

Comment: In your situation, the values of the column "A" are the date object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

- In your screenshot, `2238-01-03` is a **valid** date. In order to consider it as **invalid** you need to set up some manual rules. Since the column name is **timestamp**, I assume that all the future dates (tomorrow or later dates) are **invalid** dates.
- Therefore, the following script will **remove** a row if the corresponding value in column **A** is either a **valid future date** or an **invalid date** ( e.g. `hi`).
- The `if` condition to achieve that is:

  `dtObj>today || (!(dtVals[i] instanceof Date) && isNaN(dtVals[i]))`

---

### Solution:

```
function invalidDates() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('TempDataSet');
  const sz=sh.getRange('A:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  const dtVals = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sz).getValues().flat();  
  const today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");

for (let i = dtVals.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
var dtObj = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dtVals[i]), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  if (  dtObj>today || (!(dtVals[i] instanceof Date) && isNaN(dtVals[i])) ) {
    sh.deleteRow(i+2);
  }
}
}
```

---

### Related:

[Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)